# How are echo and print different in PHP?

Tags: php, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference: Comparing PHP's print and echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo)

Is there any major and fundamental difference between these two functions in PHP?

Answer (score 304, accepted):

From:
http://web.archive.org/web/20090221144611/http://faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/1/fid/40

1. Speed.  There is a difference between the two, but speed-wise it
   should be irrelevant which one you use.  echo is marginally faster 
   since it doesn't set a return value if you really want to get down to the
   nitty gritty.
2. Expression. `print()` behaves like a function in that you can do: 
   `$ret = print "Hello World"`; And `$ret` will be `1`.  That means that print
   can be used as part of a more complex expression where echo cannot.  An
   example from the PHP Manual:

```php
$b ? print "true" : print "false";
```

print is also part of the precedence table which it needs to be if it 
is to be used within a complex expression. It is just about at the bottom
of the precedence list though.  Only `,` `AND` `OR` `XOR` are lower.

3. Parameter(s).  The grammar is: `echo expression [, expression[,
   expression] ... ]` But `echo ( expression, expression )` is not valid. 
   This would be valid: `echo ("howdy"),("partner")`; the same as: `echo
   "howdy","partner"`; (Putting the brackets in that simple example 
   serves
   no purpose since there is no operator precedence issue with a single
   term like that.)

So, echo without parentheses can take multiple parameters, which get
concatenated:

```
   echo  "and a ", 1, 2, 3;   // comma-separated without parentheses
   echo ("and a 123");        // just one parameter with parentheses
```

`print()` can only take one parameter:

```
   print ("and a 123");
   print  "and a 123";
```

Comment: Echo can also be used in a ternary operation:

echo ($b) ? 'true' : 'false';

Comment: @philjohn I'm pretty sure your statement is equavalent to: echo (($b) ? 'true' : 'false'); and not: (echo ($b)) ? 'true' : 'false'; So echo is not part of the actual condition in the ternary operation.

Comment: In the interests of making something not doable with `echo`: `$b ? print "true" : die("false");`

Comment: @Bart print is also not part of the condition in dl__'s example and including it would be a redundant thing.  philjohn's example has exactly the same output as dl__'s example.

Comment: Proof of print being a language construct is also naturally in PHP's sourcecode; see  http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l#1146    as well as http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#850.

Comment: From w3C: The PHP print Statement: print is also a language construct,

Comment: you can `echo(print('test'))` but 
you cannot `print(echo('test'))`

Answer (score 77):

They are:

- print only takes one parameter, while echo can have multiple parameters.
- print returns a value (1), so can be used as an expression.
- echo is slightly faster.

Answer (score 10):

I think `print()` is slower than `echo`.

I like to use `print()` only for situations like:

```
 echo 'Doing some stuff... ';
 foo() and print("ok.\n") or print("error: " . getError() . ".\n");
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear , Sir ?

Comment: Wow, this is a really bad answer from nine years ago, I don't think there's any way we can improve it. Sorry!

Comment: @Legend I think @grilix is referring to the ability for print() to return 1. if the `foo()` function returns false, then the `and` part is false... so that allows the second part of the evaluation ( after the `or` ) to execute. It's an interesting use of `print` that I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 9):

To add to the answers above, while print can only take one parameter, it will allow for concatenation of multiple values, ie:

```
$count = 5;

print "This is " . $count . " values in " . $count/5 . " parameter";
```

This is 5 values in 1 parameter

Answer (score 6):

As the PHP.net manual suggests, take a read of [this discussion](http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/1/fid/40).

One major difference is that `echo` can take multiple parameters to output. E.g.:

```
echo 'foo', 'bar';   // Concatenates the 2 strings
print('foo', 'bar'); // Fatal error
```

If you're looking to evaluate the outcome of an output statement (as below) use `print`. If not, use `echo`.

```
$res = print('test');
var_dump($res); //bool(true)
```

Comment: echo doesn't accept echo('foo','bar');, but does accept echo 'foo', 'bar';

Comment: I know this answer is old, but doesn't `print` ALWAYS return 1?  Besides, when and why would you ever need to test to be sure something printed out?  That is just straight up NOT NEEDED, EVER!  Quite frankly, print is useless and should be removed, in favor of ECHO!