# Is there any difference between 'print' and 'echo' in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are echo and print different in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php)

UPDATE :

I found to my relief an **exact** [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php) (it wasn't showing up when I typed this question at first, I found it with ... google):
Please vote with me to close this question, because it's tiring, go hunt that other poor guy a bit ;-)

---

Is there any difference between `print` and `echo` in PHP? If so, which should I use and when? If not, why are there two keywords?

UPDATE :

At the downvoters : please read the SO faq. SO was setup also to capture googleable questions. so you shouldn't downvote for that, this question is a valid question, answered on a lot of places and now on SO too.

Of course you can downvote for another reason, but please leave a comment in the lines of 
-1 : downvoted for .. , cause for now, I'm not understanding the downvotes.

Comment: "Googleable" as a tag implies that you are terribly, terribly lazy for asking a question. I removed it to protect you from yourself.

Comment: @Welbog, that's fine for me, but I put it there with some reaons. 1) using SO in stead of google is OK, its meant score high on google so it has to have coverage of existing answers. Not everyone seems to know this, normally if I ask a googleable question, I am voted down, certainly by newbies, since on ohter forums, asking googleable questions is not done, so in way it is to protect myself
2. By stating googleable, i hope on quick responses of people who will google it, so I can really use it in stead of google , while still helping extending the knowledge base here

Comment: I have to agree with Peter. That fact that something is "googleable" shouldn't mean anything. The vast majority of questions here could be considered "googleable."

Comment: @Jonathan : Than again : since the majority of questions is googleable,  the tag might not be that usefull :-)

Comment: I wonder who invented "RTFM" ;)

Comment: @NinethSense, someone without any teaching skills?

Comment: Googleable is not a tag, and for a reason. Please don't add nonsense, useless tags.

Comment: regardless of whether a question is googlable or not, the tag is useless.  If you're afraid of downvotes, this may not be the correct site for you.

Comment: @all, you are talking about a tag that was removed 7 hours a go, and that was not put back. I had a point with that tag that I described in a comment.  All in good faith and with best intentions, but I appreciate nobody else likes that tag, so I never put it back.

Comment: @Peter, spoon feeding answers is not teaching. Showing others how to find the answer themselves is much more valuable. The whole give a man a fish, feed him for a day - teach a man to fish and feed him for a lifetime thing. I'm having trouble with your logic... why not just ask a question about every function in PHP and put a googleable tag on it? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Mike: Ok one last time and very clear now : I think the googleable tag was a mistake and not thought trouhg.  I stated in a comment myself : "Than again : since the majority of questions is googleable, the tag might not be that usefull :-) " Also in a comment I explained why I thougt first it might be usefull.  (Althoug reactions as  belgariontheking show its not that clear). So far for the tag now I hope.  As far as the question goes : see next comment :-)

Comment: @Mike : the question is not spoonfeeding, I *am* a beginner (@php that is), and added that tag too, which was removed for unclear reasons.  I didnot put that back, because I never "tagfight".  I really had that question and decided not to google on it, but to SO on it, which is supposed to be OK.  Only the majority of the SO userbase doesn't seem to know that.  SO results are better than googles in the first place, all the relevant things are voted up, and secondly now a search on "print echo difference" should give this (good) result on it one day. It's a win win situation, but nobody

Comment: seems to care about that philosophy (which is of course not mine)

Comment: It just seems to be like you're trying to duplicate PHP's manual on SO simply because it's easier to search here than php.net. Not to mention the potential for rep whoring due to this philosophy. The differences between the 2 functions are clearly defined and cited on both pages in PHP's manual and I'm sure there are several comments making similar contributions. When you have question about a specific function, I don't understand why you would come to SO first instead of one of the best programming language manuals in the world.

Comment: @Mike I don't even understand the repwhoring concept : it's not like it's money or anyting? Or can you cash it in somewhere, that would be nice..(for Jon S. anyway) No, I read somewhere that it was OK to use SO in stead of google (and it was about asking a new question) so I did it, end of the story.  But since nobody likes a googleable question, everybody is voting down.  So far for repwhoring, and so for also for the SO goals..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [this link](http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/1/fid/40), suggested by the [PHP manual entry for the `echo()` function](http://www.php.net/echo):

> 1. Speed.  There is a difference between the two, but speed-wise it
>      should be irrelevant which one you
>      use.  echo is marginally faster  since
>      it doesn't set a return value if you
>      really want to get down to the nitty
>      gritty.
> 2. Expression.  print() behaves like a function in that you can do:  $ret =
>      print "Hello World"; And $ret will be
> 3. That means that print can be used as part of a more complex expression
>      where echo cannot.  An example from
>      the PHP Manual:
>
>    $b ? print "true" : print "false";
>
> print is also part of the precedence
>   table which it needs to be if it  is
>   to be used within a complex
>   expression. It is just about at the
>   bottom of the precedence list though. 
>   Only "," AND, OR and XOR are lower.
>
> 3. Parameter(s).  The grammar is: echo expression [, expression[, expression]
>      ... ] But echo ( expression,
>      expression ) is not valid.  This would
>      be valid: echo ("howdy"),("partner");
>      the same as: echo "howdy","partner";
>      (Putting the brackets in that simple
>      example  serves no purpose since there
>      is no operator precedence issue with a
>      single term like that.)
>
> So, echo without parentheses can take
>   multiple parameters, which get
>   concatenated:
>
> echo  "and a ", 1, 2, 3;   //
>   comma-separated without parentheses
>   echo ("and a 123");        // just one
>   parameter with parentheses
>
> print() can only take one parameter:
>
> print ("and a 123");    print  "and
>   a 123";

Answer (score 4):

some say echo is slightly faster than print since it has no return value.  though here is someone who doesn't think the speed difference matters much... http://fabien.potencier.org/article/8/print-vs-echo-which-one-is-faster

Answer (score 3):

[the answer is in the docs.](http://php.net/print)

Answer (score 2):

print returns, echo does not.

And you are right, totally googleable.