# When should I use print instead of echo in PHP?

Tags: php, printing, echo

I understand that echo is slightly faster, and print can be used as a function, but I've been reading an e-book on PHP, and the writer is using print, instead of echo, to output very simple text.

```
print "Your name is $name\n";
```

So my question is, when would it be appropriate for me to use print as opposed to echo?

Comment: **Duplicates:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006586/is-there-any-difference-between-print-and-echo-in-php-closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504797/php-echo-print-printf

Comment: Not quite duplicates, actually. Those are asking the differences, where as I'm asking when it would be appropriate to differentiate.

Comment: Rob, you better find yourself another question to ask, a bit more useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never.

Definitely a micro optimisation.

*Some* may find it useful as the *and print* [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401/hidden-features-of-php/173907#173907). But ugly as hell and not recommended.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: Ah I see. Looks easier than an isset, but you're right, its ugly as hell.

Comment: However, aside from the ugliness, why don't you recommend it? Is there some drawback to it?

Comment: @Rob I was just testing it and kept getting an error. I might remove that section.

Comment: Oh. So then mostly just micro optimization?

Comment: Yes, plus I'll guarantee that 99% of PHP apps out there use `echo`.

Comment: About the "Unless you require to know if the print was successful or not" part - from http://www.php.net/print - "Returns 1, always."

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the main difference is that you can print multiple values with `echo` without concatenating them, i.e., `echo $a, $b, $c;`. As far as I know, it's not possible to do this with `print`. If you want to use this syntax (and I would advise to use it whenever possible, although I'm not 100% sure that it is faster in real-world apps), it would be better to *always* use `echo`, as mixing both ways would lead to inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter. This kind of optimization is most of the time micro optimization, which most of the time is fruitless.

Comment: Well, there are maybe some obscure edgecases where it would make a difference, but 'most of the time' it does not.

Comment: a loop with 1e15 times echo or print would make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

print and echo are commands used to output information to the visitors screen (on the web page). Both do the same job, so it usually comes down to a matter of personal preference on which one you like to use.

There is a slight difference between print and echo which would depend on how you want to use the outcome. Using the print method can return a true/false value. This may be helpful during a script execution of somesort. Echo does not return a value, but has been considered as a faster executed command. All this can get into a rather complicated discussion, so for now, you can just use whichever one you prefer.

Comment: You *can't* get true/false with print. From manual - "Returns 1, always" (it's not even a boolean).