# Differences between echo, echo(), print and print() in PHP

Tags: php, printing, echo

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How are echo and print different in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php)
>   [Is there any difference between ‘print’ and ‘echo’ in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006586/is-there-any-difference-between-print-and-echo-in-php)
>   [What’s the difference of echo,print,print_r in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-of-echo-print-print-r-in-php)

There are several ways to print output in PHP; including but not limited to:

```
echo 'Hello';
echo ('Hello');
print 'Hello';
print ('Hello');
```

Are there any differences between these four? Also, do the parentheses make any difference at all?

Comment: Why do all the 'duplicate' answers lead to 'closed as possible duplicate answers' as well?

Answer (score 2):

Two differences:

`print` has a return value (always 1), `echo` doesn't. Therefore `print` can be used as an expression.

`echo` accepts multiple arguments. So you may write `echo $a, $b` instead of `echo $a . $b`.

Concerning the parentheses: They are simply *wrong* in my eyes. They have no function at all. You could as well write `echo (((((((((($a))))))))))`; people usually include parentheses from ignorance, thinking that `print` is a function. Furthermore it increases the chance of misinterpretation. For example `print("foo") && print("bar")` does not print `foobar`, because PHP interprets this as `print(("foo") && print("bar"))`. So `bar1` would be printed, even though it looks different.

Comment: I know Python is not PHP, but they [banned](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) the use of `print 'something'`, now you always have to use `print('something')` with the parentheses.

Comment: Also see: http://www.ideone.com/LUOOG

Comment: No. It does make a difference. Even though it outputs the same the version with parentheses *looks* different. The parentheses and function like formatting make it look different. At least I would be fooled into thinking that it outputs `foobar`, if I didn't stop to think about it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it outputs the same thing. Maybe I didn't explain my point clearly. I'm talking about the understandability of the code, not of the functionality. The functionality doesn't change, that's correct.

Comment: Though there actually is one case, there using parentheses will not only make the code less understandable, but will actually break things. If you have a function which returns by reference `return($a)` will not work, because it will not return a reference to `$a`, but the result of the expression `($a)`, which obviously is a value, not a reference. But this is off topic, because we're talking about print and echo ^^

Comment: @nik Do elaborate. I can't see how it would be different

Comment: @nik the part about references

Comment: Simply see the third note on http://php.net/return. It is explained there.