# The echo and print statements in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is basic difference echo Vs print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615679/what-is-basic-difference-echo-vs-print)

The  echo and  print statements are nearly identical, but they have some differences.
For example, the print statement returns a value of 1 if it is successful
or a value of 0 if it is not successful, while the echo statement does
not return a value.

**why print statement returns a value of 1 if it is successful. but echo doesn't**. thank you

Comment: Both are language constructs. `print` behaves like a function/expression, while `echo` may only be used as statement.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, maybe this was done by design with echo being a sort of use and forget operation. @mario: Could you go into more detail into what you mean by echo being only used as a statement.

Comment: `echo` accepts a variable number of arguments to be printed out. But it only does so when used without parenthesis. And this would be ambigious and unparseable in an expression. That's why `echo` can only be used as statement (meaning only command in a line). - More links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542745/differences-between-echo-echo-print-and-print-in-php

Answer (score 1):

I've actually taken advantage of the return value of the print "function" in an ajax call:

```
return print json_encode($my_data);
```

It doesn't do anything at all with the return value, but it terminates the execution of the current script, which is a slightly prettier way of writing

```
echo json_encode($my_data);
die();
```

But as to why one returns something and the other doesn't.... probably isn't a terrible good reason for it. I reckon echo is ever so slightly (negligibly) faster because of it, whereas print has weird uses such as the aforementioned one.

As to what these other guys are saying about `print()` not being a language construct, but a function, I say to you, [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php). It's a language construct too.