# PHP 5.3 incompatible - <? and <?php . How to fix?

Tags: php, php-5.3, incompatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [<? ?> tags not working in php 5.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1)

I am running Debian Lenny and the "official" PHP version is 5.2.? -- However, I've ran across many things that now require PHP 5.3. After some googling, I have found a site to help me force debian lenny to go to 5.3.

Now I know a lot of things will break with 5.3. I don't seem to have that problem with most of the things I use. However one major problem I have always had was that I used the shorthand method of starting php code with:
`<?` instead of the `<?php`. This was never an issue in PHP 5.2.? because it accepted both.

However, in PHP 5.3.5.0 from dotdeb it seems like the php is required. I went through and replaced all `<?` with `<?php` and then replaced all `<?phpphp` with `<?php`. That seems to have taken care of any issues I had with my code, however the shortcut in third party code such as `<?=` does not work as `<?php=`. I also do not wish to run this replacement on every php file I use from here on out.

How can I get php 5.3.? to allow both the shortcut `<?` and `<?=` to be accepted and not require the php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) in `php.ini`.

See also: [<? ?> tags not working in php 5.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1)

Comment: -1 Normally I do not downvote people answering on duplicates. But in this particular case one just has to: You **know** that there is a duplicate and you **still** answer it?

Comment: @Gordon, @nikic: I answered, then found the duplicate afterwards. By that point, the answer seemed to be liked, so I let it be.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to php.ini you could try using an .htaccess file:

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

.htaccess:

```
php_value short_open_tag "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

search for `<?=`

replace with `<?php echo`

Answer (score 0):

Its in the php.ini settings.
If you have a webmin panel it's easy setting it up by going to others PHP config -> manage and then other settings.
Else you have to do manual editing and search for manual_open_tag