# PHP shorthand isn't working on new server?

Tags: php, linux, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [<? ?> tags not working in php 5.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1)

I usually use shorthand syntax

```
 <?="hello";?>
```

instead of

```
 <?php echo "hello";?>
```

I created a development server and installed same version of php but shorthand method doesn't work, why? how can I fix it?

I would ask this on the server site, but this is related to a php setting or something I believe.

I'm running linux fedora 14

Comment: Unless you know the key phrase for this issue (that <? versus <?php is "short hand"), this is a difficult problem to do a web search for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to enable the [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) option in the configuration file `php.ini` (probably in `/etc/`). As you have discovered, short tags are disabled by default.

**Edit:** and yes, as @Sebastian P points out, this has been asked before.

Answer (score 2):

Find your php.ini file in the apache directory and change short_open_tag = On

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to enable short tags, which is an ini setting as you supposed.

You should note that short tags are regarded by some as a bad idea (myself included).  I know they are handy and thus tempting, but this question illustrates the reason why NOT to use them - what if you move your code and CANNOT enable them (for whatever reason)?  The most portable code does not use short tags.  If you need to turn them on to make old code work, then do what you have to do.  If you're setting up a server to start a new project, leave 'em off!

Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: I totally agree now. I was a self-taught programmer and saw a friend using them saying it's no big deal. Now I regret it. I turned on the short_open_tag in php.ini but it' still not working.

Comment: Did you reboot the server?  Gotta reboot after INI change.  Also, check out your phpinfo() and make sure that the INI you're editing is the one the server is using.  As long as you're using PHP5 or greater, this is a PER_DIR setting, so you'll also need to verify that no .htaccess file is overriding your INI setting.