# MYSQL While loop using PHP

Tags: php

Here is a paragraph of PHP Code:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC";
 // OREDER BY id DESC is order result by descending

 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     ?><td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['view']; ?></td><?php
  }
```

In reality there are several `<?php  ?>` tags when switching to HTML but to make the code more readable, I excluded them. Could someone explain how this works? I can not find anything online informing me how this works.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ ?

Comment: @zerkms you beat me too it :D

Answer (score 0):

I hope these links help.

[Escaping from HTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

[what is the recommended way to embed html codes inside php codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054780/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-embed-html-codes-inside-php-codes)

It's good to know this ability exist in `PHP` so in the future if you need help for a specific case for this issue after some trials, you can easily get help in SO.

How this is working (from php.net manual): *Everything outside of a pair of opening and closing tags is ignored by the PHP parser which allows PHP files to have mixed content. This allows PHP to be embedded in HTML documents*