# all mode embedded php in html and html in php

Tags: php

I want to know(all ways) that php embedded in html and html in php.
I know this ways:

```
<?php
echo '<p>text here</p>';
?>
<p>Some of this text is static, <?php echo 'text here'; ?></p>

<?php echo '<p>'; ?>
html text here...
<?php echo '</p>';?>

embedding in conditional 
<?php if(conditions) { ?>
... HTML CODE ...
<?php } ?>

Embeding in ul
<ul> 
<?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>
<li>Menu Item <?php echo $i; ?></li> 
<?php } ?>
</ul>

embeding in forms and textarea

<form action = “…..” method = “post”>
Type your name:<br><input type = “text” name = “name” value = <?php code here...?>”<br>
                  <input type = “submit” value = “submit”>
</form>
<textarea rows = “7” cols=”25”><?php cod here.... ?></textarea>
```

Please give me other mode that php embed html and html embed php.It's very important for me!

Comment: templating engines are the only other way i can think of.. SMARTY, Dwoo, Savant, Pear.. List goes on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it. The first one for embedding PHP in HTML:

```
<html> 
 <title>HTML with PHP</title>
 <body>
 <h1>My Example</h1>

 <?php
 //your php code here
 ?>

 <b>Here is some more HTML</b>

 <?php
 //more php code
 ?>


 </body>
 </html>
```

And the other, to embed HTML in PHP, with echo:

```
<?php 
 Echo "<html>";
 Echo "<title>HTML with PHP</title>";
 Echo "<b>My Example</b>";

 //your php code here

 Print "<i>Print works too!</i>"; 
 ?>
```

You might find this [tutorial](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2001/05/03/php_foundations.html) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054780/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-embed-html-codes-inside-php-codes) useful.

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not know about html. All PHP knows is strings. Php code can be embedded anywhere in your document with `<?= value ?>` and `<?php statements; ?>`.

Comment: man if you do not know examples ... let others. 
Php does not rely only on words.. is based on examples to understand..because i'm begginer

Comment: @Danut: Find a html example. Now take any piece of text within the file, and replace it with `<?= "that piece of text"?>`