# Keeping right and wrong answers in PHP

Tags: php

I'm beginner in PHP. I'm trying to write a number guess script with two files.

`try.php`

```
<?php
echo "<html><head><title>Calculator Game From 1998</title></head><body>";
echo "<h1>Please Guess The Answer</h1>";
echo "<form name = \"myfirstform\" action  = \"formprocess.php\" method = \"POST\">";
echo "Enter Integer Between 1-5<br>";
echo "<input type = \"text\" name = \"firstdata\">";
echo "<br> <input type= \"submit\" value = \"submit\">";
echo "</form>";
echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

`formprocess.php`

```
<?php
$random = rand(1, 5);
echo "<html><head><title>Answer</title></head><body>";
if ($_POST["firstdata"] == $random) {
  echo "<h1><font color=\"green\">Congrulations!</h1></font><br>";
  echo "<h2>Answer was: </h2>";
  echo $random;
  echo "<br>";  
  echo "<a href=\"try.php\">new game</a>";
}
else {
  echo "<h1><font color=\"red\">Nope wrong answer</h1></font><br>";
  echo "<h2>Answer was: </h2>";
  echo $random;
  echo "<br>";  
  echo "<a href=\"try.php\">new game</a>";
}  
echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

The question is I want to keep win and loose numbers for each players. I try to add variables

```
$win = 0;
$lost = 0;
```

and try to increase them one in if sections. But it doesn't work because it will be 0 again after refreshing the page.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to save information between page loads, you'll need to store it somehow. You can add it to a database, or use sessions.

Comment: Using this many `echo` estatements to output HTML is not a very good approach. Your code will quickly be unreadable. See other questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054780/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-embed-html-codes-inside-php-codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would be to use sessions. You can use the `$_SESSION` variable to keep track of the score. The `$_SESSION` variable is stored on the server, and a cookie on the user's computer is used to match the browser session to the user's `$_SESSION` variable:

As the first line of `formprocess.php`, include this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['wins']) || !isset($_SESSION['losses'])) {
    $_SESSION['wins'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['losses'] = 0;
}
```

Then, in your `if` statement, you would increment the wins or losses:

```
if ($_POST["firstdata"] == $random) {
    $_SESSION['wins']++;
    // other stuff...
} else {
    $_SESSION['losses']++;
    // other stuff
}

echo "<p>You've won {$_SESSION['wins']} games and lost {$_SESSION['losses']}.</p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Each request is stateless so you need a way to store the variables between requests. In your case, the simplest way is with [session variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['win'])) {
    $_SESSION['win'] = 0;
}

// ...

if ($_POST["firstdata"] == $random) {
   $_SESSION['win'] += 1;

   // ...
```

From there you should be able to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take a look at using $_SESSION variables for your formprocess.php file. Be sure to add session_start(); after the opening php tag, and then assign your $_SESSION variables to your win and loss variables like this:

```
$_SESSION['win'] = $win;
```

When each time you come back to the page, the variable will hold the count. And if you want to add to that number (after you've done some checking to make sure) you can add to it like so:

```
$_SESSION['win'] = ($_SESSION['win'] + $win);
```

That will add total amount in the $_SESSION['win'] variable to the total amount in the $win variable and give you a new total in $_SESSION['win'].

Also be sure to add the session_start(); just after the opening php tag in your try.php file as well or you will lose the $_SESSION variables.