# What are some good tips for writing php files along side raw html?

Tags: php, html

I do not like spitting back html with php's echo, makes it hard to do and read nested elements. So I usually write conditions that write raw html and make it as readable as possbile when editing the file directly or viewing the output html through the browser. However, I cannot find a style that stays readable for long. Any suggestions?

```
<?
if($foo == $bar)
{
?>
  <div>
    <p>hello, world</p>
  </div>
<?
}
?>
```

As you can see, it doesn't look too good. At least not to me, but it makes the browser output more readable so I can better check the it for any mistakes.

i dont want this:

```
<?
if($foo == $bar)
{
  echo "<div>\n\t<p>hello, world</p>\n</div>\n";
}
?>
```

Is my approach incorrect to begin with? should I use php to output to a .html file? and just view from the browser for mistakes and do as much php as possible inside the php file?

Comment: php is server side language so best practice is do not embed html in php.

Comment: Have you looked into template engines like twig or smarty? Do a quick search and see if they might be along the lines of what you are looking for (they might not be).

Comment: there are lots of template engines for PHP as @CMiller have mentioned, aside from the 2 he mentioned, blade template is also quiet popular

Comment: cool i was unaware of these engines. I will certainly play around with them. however this does not answer my question, I'm looking for tips when writing code myself, without the aid of a generator, on how to manage php and html to be readable when either editing the file and viewing the output source after php executes.

Comment: Indeed. These are only comments *because* they are not answers. Lawrences has a pretty good answer and if it does work for you it might be worth marking it as answered. It's pretty clean looking if you have to go that route.

Comment: I find echo much easier to read. Switching back and forth makes it hard to read for me and it's very easy to miss place a tag above or below the open/close tag or forget to open or close a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your right it's not nice, instead use proper [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), for content with a large amount of HTML:

```
<?php if($foo == $bar): ?>
<div>
    <p>hello, world</p>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

I don't believe you need a seperate template language to write maintainable code, PHP is perfectly fine in outputting variables in HTML.

Really the problem is seperating your logic from your output which a template engine can't help with if your not structuring your code properly in the first place. For example stuffing it all in an index.php file or not using MVC whereas you don't put HTML with your logic.

If you have a large project or are overly concerned with separating your PHP from your views, or you want the features which come with a template engine like built in caching and slots etc, then use one. But maybe first look at learning a framework which will improve your overall codebase as most frameworks come with their own. Though essentially you can achieve the same thing including nesting partials and blocks/slots with a 20 line view class which uses ob_* functions, which doesn't require you to learn a new syntax.

Rant over.. :s

Answer (score 2):

Use a templating system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) so you can separate your logic from your display code.It also allows you to bring in a designer that can work with html and might not know php at all. Smarty templates read more like HTML than PHP and that can make a big difference when dealing with a designer.

Ansered by @boatcoder

You can learn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054780/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-embed-html-codes-inside-php-codes)

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of templating engine, your best bet is @Lawrence's answer or this littly modified syntax of your first exemple (trimminig space and php tag) :

```
<? if($foo == $bar) { ?>
  <div>
    <p>hello, world</p>
  </div>
<? } ?>
```