# Installing coordino on wamp

Tags: php, apache

I found this clone of stackoverflow, and it's in php (that's the reason I want it).

I was trying for last week to install it, but unsuccessfully. I'am using wamp, mod_rewrite is enabled, and I put AllowOverride all.

But again it's not working. What I get as output is when I go to localhost is:

```
Warning (512): C:\wamp\www\app\tmp\cache\ is not writable [CORE\cake\libs\cache\file.php, line 267]
Warning (2): include_once(C:\wamp\www\app\config\database.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [CORE\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php, line 23]
Warning (2): include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'C:\wamp\www\app\config\database.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\wamp\www;C:\wamp\www\app\;.;C:\php\pear') [CORE\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php, line 23]css('install.css');?> image('coordino_logo.png');?> 
changer de langue
link(__('english',true),'/lang/eng')?>
link(__('french',true),'/lang/fre')?>
flash(); ?>
```

Download code for coordino is here: [coordino](https://github.com/Datawalke/Coordino)

If anyone can help me, please do so. What I need is tutorial on how to install this application. Thank you for any kind of help and useful information.

Comment: The first warning says a cache folder is not writable. Have you checked to make sure it exists in Windows? Have you also checked to ensure the database.php file exists in the config folder? What have you tried?

Comment: @Cogicero I have been googling and trying to find solution, I'm newbie to this php things. What I find is that this mod_rewrite and AllowOverride may cause troubles, and I changed that. I don't know how can I do anything else. In tutorial for this app it says just unzip and go to link (but evidently it's not so). I didn't check for database.php. What shell I do if it doesn't exist? Thank you for response and your help.

Comment: Just checked and there is this file: database.php.default

Comment: Ok Balboa. Rename database.php.default to database.php and also ensure that the folder C:\wamp\www\app\tmp\cache exists. If it doesn't, create it.

Comment: @Cogicero I did so, and now warning 512 is gone, but still it doesn't work, the next two warnings(2) are still present, and I don't get to the installation process. Thank you for being willing to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a database.php file inside your C:\wamp\www\app\config\ folder? The error makes it appear like there is none.

Make sure you rename the database.php.default file to database.php and make sure it is inside the C:\wamp\www\app\config\ folder.

Comment: I just did so, there was file named database_sample.php, and I renamed it into database.php, now warnings are gone :). but still no installation process. now on screen I have: css('install.css');?> image('coordino_logo.png');?> 
changer de langue
link(__('english',true),'/lang/eng')?>
link(__('french',true),'/lang/fre')?>
flash(); ?>  I don't know is this looking ok in comment but I cannot put it as code.

Comment: and at the very last this thing solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1. Thank you Cogicero for your help. I will see, if I manage to install it properly I will edit this question, and write tutorial by myself for others experiencing same problem. :)

Comment: Sorry I have been offline for a bit. Aha short tags! Smh. Alright, glad to be of help. Will you accept my answer then? To accept an answer just click the checkmark button on the left.