# Coordino installation Issue ?

Tags: php, installation

I downloaded the `Cordino` from [here](https://github.com/Datawalke/Coordino) and put it in wamp directory www. Tried chekcing it on `http://localhost/Coordino-master/` but that gives error

[image: First Error]
 and this one 
[image: Second one]

I looked for it and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302623/installing-coordino-on-wamp) but this didnt help either. 
I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

What the good devs at Coordino fail to mention - is that the application is built with CakePHP

So, in addition to using the re-write config found here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

You must also tell apache that the root directory is

```
app/webroot/
```

i.e. 
so that `localhost` resolves to `localhost/app/webroot/` (assuming you move the contents of Coordino-master/ into your root-web-directory)
without that fact being apparent to the user--

If I can clarify any further, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

which web-server are you using ?
for best results with coordino you must use Apache or NGINX web-server
you can see this tutorial on how to install it properly
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxtc32nMi30