# <?=$variable?> is not working

Tags: php, php-ini

We have moved our project to a new server 
with
PHP Version 5.3.10 
(Linux ip-10-145-181-140 3.2.0-24-virtual #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 12:51:49 UTC 2012 i686)

now `<?=$variable?>`  is not working here.

`<?php echo $variable; ?>`  is working

but our project is crowed with `<?=$variable?>`

how to change the php.ini/server setting  to run   this code?

Comment: or upgrade to PHP 5.4 :)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [<? ?> tags not working in php 5.3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1)

Answer (score 5):

This is because its not recommended to use them. Nevertheless, look for you `php.ini` file and edit the `short_open_tag` option to `1`.

Restart web server/php

You can find where the ini file is sitting by creating a `.php` file in your webroot as so:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```