# how to Set default department according to staff department on osticket system

Tags: php, selection, default

Is there a simple way to set the Department to a default when creating a new ticket in the Staff interface according to staff department on osticket system?

here is the original code of newticket.php

```
<td align="left"><b>Departement</b></td>
    <td>
        <select name="deptId">
            <option value="" selected >Select Department</option>
            <?
             $services= db_query('SELECT dept_id,dept_name FROM '.DEPT_TABLE.' ORDER BY dept_name');
             while (list($deptId,$dept) = db_fetch_row($services)){

                $selected = ($info['deptId']==$deptId)?'selected':''; ?>
                <option value="<?=$deptId?>"<?=$selected?>><?=$dept?></option>
            <?
            }?>
        </select>
        &nbsp;<font class="error"><b>*</b>&nbsp;<?=$errors['deptId']?></font>
    </td>
```

any help will be appreciated

clarification:
the original code of osticket system when create a new ticket, the staff have an options to choose department even not their department. here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX3ms.jpg)

my questions is it possible to set department automatically when created  new ticket?
for example staff A on accounting department, so when staff A open new ticket they don't need to select department anymore.it will be automatic store as accounting dept.. i hope this is more clearly...

Comment: please elaborate more .. sorry cant grasp your problem .. atleast not me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link:

[<? ?> tags not working in php 5.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1)

"Short tags are disabled by default. I do not recommend you to use short tags ( or ). You should use the full length tags ().
However to enable short tags enable the setting called short_open_tag in the php.ini file."

1).enable "short_open_tag"
   this may be help for you..
   and use "echo or =" before the values.

2).or use this code with full length php tags.

```
<td align="left"><b>Departement</b></td>
    <td>
        <select name="deptId">
            <option value="" selected >Select Department</option>
            <?php
             $services= db_query('SELECT dept_id,dept_name FROM '.DEPT_TABLE.' ORDER BY dept_name');
             while (list($deptId,$dept) = db_fetch_row($services)){

                $selected = ($info['deptId']==$deptId)?'selected':''; ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $deptId;?>" <?php echo $selected;?> > <?php echo $dept;?> </option>
            <?php
            }?>
        </select>
        &nbsp;<font class="error"><b>*</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $errors['deptId'];?></font>
    </td>
```

Comment: what i planned is the staff doesn't need to select dept...it will be goes to automatic according to the staff dept.

Comment: Which means you have logged in as a staff.In that staff profile one field as the department. So in this page you have to default select as that department only. is it correct? then give me the department name variable and values.

Comment: yes correct..that was i planned...
sorry i don't understand about department name variable and values.did you mean this dept_name and dept_id?? really sorry because i am a beginner on php scripts

Comment: yes for example that's logged-in staff dept_name as "ticketing" means that "ticketing" department as selected from the dropdown for that staff right. is it correct means? from his profile values has following format "$Name='fedrick';$Userid=1;$DeptName='ticketing';$DeptID=4;" from this you have compare both details.

Comment: $selected = ($DeptID==$deptId)?'selected':''; ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $deptId;?>" <?php echo $selected;?> > <?php echo $dept;?> </option>   **$DeptID as the profile value and $deptId as the db value. and then your  comparison like this 4==1=>notselected,4==2=>notselected,4==3=>notselected,4==4=>selected**  ok is it clear?