# Undefined variable when code works in hosted server

Tags: php, php-5.3

Trying to help someone with their php based site, I cannot run it locally as I get errors for '**Undefined variable: dbhost**' etc. when trying to use any page that connects to mysql.

dbConfig.php:

```
<?

$dbhost="HOST"; // Host name 
$dbusername="USER"; // Mysql username 
$dbuserpass="PASS"; // Mysql password 
$dbname="NAME"; // Database name 

?>
```

Excerpt from including php file (e.g. login.php):

```
include_once ("../include/dbConfig.php");
$db_handle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpass) or die(mysql_error());
```

This works fine in his hosted server solution on PHP 5.1. My local setup is Apache & PHP 5.5 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the shorthand `<?` for starting php comment blocks, you need to enable the directive `short_open_tag` in php.ini.

The ***default has changed*** for new installations since 5.3, see: [<? ?> tags not working in php 5.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1)

It is recommended not to use them and change older code to use the full `<?php` syntax rather than enabling this tag - [PEAR coding standards for tags](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.tags.php). There are also some rumors that they would be deprecated for PHP 6, but these seem unfounded as I was unable to find any official source.