# selecting from database not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, while-loop

Can anyone see an error in this code, it works in my localhost but not on a live server

```
<?
$query = "select * from mytable";
$user_result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());

while ($user_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_result)) {


    echo "<table CELLPADDING=10 border =1 >";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo  "<td>".$user_array['email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_array['firstname']."</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

}

mysql_close();
?>
```

It is simply just displaying the text `""; echo ""; echo "".$user_array['email'].""; echo "".$user_array['firstname'].""; echo ""; echo ""; } mysql_close(); ?> "`

Comment: change `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using short tags `<? ?>`, and for that you need short_open_tag enabled in your php.ini file. The server probably has that variable set to false. Here's the [documentation on opening and closing tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). Change them to

```
<?php    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this -

```
<?  to  <?php
```

**OR** set below in your `php.ini` on server

```
short_open_tag=On
```

**Explanation**: Your local server is enabled with using php short tags. But on your server its not. So either you can change the config on your server or avoid using short tags

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you don't have `short_open_tag` turned on, to check it out see `phpinfo()`, otherwise change `<?` to `<?php`

You'll find interesting `php.ini` variables definitions [HERE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
<?php
   //code
?>
```

while you can use

```
<?= $var ?>
```

to print your variable (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).