# My PHP file isn't showing anything?

Tags: php

I have a PHP file.

```
<?
    $user = "hi";
    echo $user;
?>
```

And nothing happens, its just blank. It should say "hi". I am using xampp to run the PHP and it is saved in the right place but nothing happens.

Comment: Make sure open short tags are on. If not, do `<?php` instead of `<?` --- Plus, make sure you're not trying to access this as a regular `.html` file in your browser, should that be the case. You will need to install PHP on your computer in order for the file to be parsed correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<? ?> tags not working in php 5.3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `<?php` instead of `<?`
try this:

```
<?php
    $user = "hi";
    echo $user;
?>
```

or Set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in **php.ini**

And restart your Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate php `short open tag` from php settongs or replace : `<?` with `<?php`