# MySQL UPDATE not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm making a site where the owner has to be able to update their events, but my update code isnt working even though im 99% sure I havent made any errors.

First the form where you press update:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id ASC";

$res = $objCon->query($sql) or die('fejl i query:'.mysqli_error($objCon));

while($row=$res->fetch_array()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo "<div class='eventpost'>";
    echo "<div class='dato'>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<p class='overskrift'>";
    echo "<a href='update.php?id=$id'>RET </a>";
    echo "<a href='code_delete.php?id=$id'>SLET</a>";
    echo $row['overskrift'];
    echo "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

then the update form:

```
<form action="code_update.php" method="POST">
    <label>Dato:<br>
    <input type="text" name="dag" value="<?php echo $data['dag']; ?>"></label>
    <label>Månede:<br>
    <input type="text" name="month" value="<?php echo $data['month']; ?>"></label>
    <label>Overskrift:<br>
    <input type="text" name="overskrift" value="<?php echo $data['overskrift']; ?>"></label>
    <label>Tekst:<br>
    <input type="text" name="tekst" value="<?php echo $data['tekst']; ?>"></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $id; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Opret">
</form>
```

and finally the update code

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['auth'] == 2){
    include('incl_db.php'); 
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $overskrift = $_POST['overskrift']; 
    $dag = $_POST['dag'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $tekst = $_POST['tekst'];
    $sql = "UPDATE events SET overskrift='$overskrift', dag='$dag', month='$month',  tekst='$tekst' WHERE id='$id'"; 
    $res = $objCon->query($sql); 

    header('location:events.php');
}else{
    header('location:index.php'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you got any error?

Comment: Remove quotes from `$id`.

Comment: No errors, removing the quotes didnt do anything

Comment: try to add to your update query this : or die('fejl i query:'.mysqli_error($objCon));

Comment: @user3751796 Can you echo $sql what it prints just write here

Comment: What do you see when you echo `$res`? And how many rows are affected (check the php output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably shorthand tags are disabled in your php version.So try changing this

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $id; ?>">
```

to this

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

You can [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1) for more.

Comment: That did it, as it turns out my new server wont register on just <?, thanks

Comment: It will make the difference if shorthand tags are not enabled. Check this for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1

Comment: welcome @Lampproductions. Pls  up vote and mark the answer as correct one if it solved your problem.