# Show Thumbnails in Backend Model Columns

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com) with Laravel.

I use File Upload / Media Finder to attach an image. I'm trying to add thumbnails to the Backend Model columns.

I tried following these guides:
https://octobercms.com/forum/post/how-to-display-pictures-in-backend-lists
https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments

---

**File Upload**

[image: file upload]

---

**Columns Thumbnail**

[image: photo]

---

### Model

I have in my Model `Catalog.php`

```
public $attachOne = [
    'photo' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

---

In `columns.yamal`

Field `photo` set to *partial* and added *path*.

---

In the partial `_photo.htm` I have

```
<?php echo $this->photo->getThumb(100, 100, ['mode' => 'crop']); ?>
```

---

### Error

I get `Error: Call to a member function getThumb() on null`.

If I use `<img src="" />` in the partial it will display an empty image in the columns, but I don't know what php to put as the src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to column widget when you are using partial `it will pass $record variable corresponding to that row`, **[** do not use `$this` there **]**

means for that row `$record` will point to current record so you can use `$record`

> your `_photo.htm` should be like this

```
<img src="<?php echo $record->photo->getThumb(100, 100, ['mode' => 'crop']); ?>" />
<!-- OR -->
<img src="<?= $record->photo->getThumb(100, 100, ['mode' => 'crop']) ?>" />
```

### update

If you are using `media finder` then you can not use `getThumb` on the file as it will be just `path for that file` **so its not possible to `resize` that image using `getThumb`** **[** Its only possible with `relational attachments (attachMany, attachone etc...)` **]**

Although you can use this to show small image

```
<img height="64" width="64" src="<?= 'https://october-plaza.com/storage/app/media/' 
. $model->photo ?>"` />
```

> you can add this **height="64" width="64"** to show image as thumbnail (but it will be full image just scale down using attributes).

if any doubts please comment

Comment: `$record` worked on pulling path from the `photo` table in database, it displays large image in backend list. But if I try to `getThumb()` it gives Error `Call to a member function getThumb() on string`.

Comment: it seems this issue related to this question as well, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648796/media-finder-display-image-on-front-end` let me update my answer

Comment: I installed Mediathumb plugin https://octobercms.com/plugin/manogi-mediathumb, it works on Frontend with Twig but not Backend in the record columns. Twig does not work in my Backend Model's partial `_photo.htm`. Only static php works but gives src(unknown) in the html. `<img src="<?php mediathumbResize($record->photo, 'height', 150, 60) ?>">`.

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo mediathumbResize(storage_path('app/media/') . $record->photo, 'height', 150, 60); ?>">` can you try this one.

Comment: I got it to work, I had to use `<?=` instead of `<?php`. Do you know why that is?

Comment: may be this is issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476072/tags-not-working-in-php-5-3-1 you need to enable `short_open_tag=On` try to check that config in `php.ini` i dont see any other this is causing this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [OCTOBER IMAGE RESIZER](https://octobercms.com/plugin/toughdeveloper-imageresizer) plugin in your columns.yaml file

**Usage in Backend List**

The image resizer can also be used on backend lists with the type of thumb, e.g.

```
image:
 label: Image
 type: thumb
 sortable: false
```

This works with:

- AttachMany (uses first image) Docs
- AttachOne Docs
- Mediafinder Docs

You can also optionally pass width (default 50), height (default 50) and options as follows:

```
image:
  label: Image
  type: thumb
  sortable: false
  width: 75
  height: 100
  options:
     mode: crop
```