# Difference in php syntax of <?php ?> and <? ?>

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between the PHP open tags “<?=” and “<?php”/“<?”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019696/what-is-the-difference-between-the-php-open-tags-and-php)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Is there really any difference in writing the syntax like `<?php ?>` or as `<? ?>`.

I was under the impression that it really didn't matter as long as the file had an .php extension. But sometimes I seem to run into problems with the  syntax.

so whats the lowdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is called shorttags.

You can disable those tags in php's configuration, apart from that there is not really a difference.

Because you can disable them, you should **not** use them, as they can cause lots of unexpected problems when you happen to run your scripts on servers where you can't enable them. Another reason, as noted by *Sjoerd* in the comment is, that they can cause conflicts when you have an XML header for instance.

If you enable short tags though, you get a shorthand syntax for the echo function: `<?= $string ?>`

It's enabled using the `short_open_tag` setting in *php.ini*. You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

**Update**
As of PHP 5.4.0 alpha1:

> `<?=` is now always available regardless of the short_tags setting
>   (Rasmus)

Comment: Indeed. You should always use the long version, in case shorttags is disabled on a server you want to deploy on. Also, take this into account when writing an `<?xml ?>` header.

Answer (score 2):

The below will work on all servers.

```
<?php // some logic in here ?> 
<?php echo "cat"; ?>
```

The below will work on servers that have their php.ini properly configured for short tags.

```
<? // some logic in here ?>
<?= "cat" ?>
```

Comment: so i guess thats why sometimes the aforementioned problems arose because of the latter syntax....

Comment: @user597272 correct, please vote my answer correct and up vote me if this is good. I survive off of points on here.

Answer (score 0):

one little dangerous thing about shorttags is that if the php.ini is set incorrectly your sourcecode is available on the internet. so