# in_array function fails

Tags: php, arrays, warnings

I'm using this line:

```
'.((isset($imgRight) && in_array(1, $imgRight)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '').'
```

and, in some cases, `$imgRight` can be **false**. That's why there's `isset()`, but it still fails.

What do I need to do to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because something is `false` doesn't mean it's not set:

```
$foo = false;
isset($foo); //true
```

You can just use:

```
($imgRight && in_array(1, $imgRight)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '')
```

or to be very safe (if imgRgiht might be null, or some non-falsey value that isn't an array):

```
((!empty($imgRight) && is_array($imgRight) && in_array(1, $imgRight)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `isset($imgRight)` to `is_array($imgRight)`.  I'm assuming that the value for the checkbox is using array notation for its value.

Answer (score 0):

`$imgRight` will pass `isset()` if it's false.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use short tags, it'll be deprecated soon!
But to your question: You need to check $imgRight for its state not for its existance (isset)! You can also shortcut some of your code here...and you should also check for it's existance though before you work with it:

```
if (isset($imgRight)) {
   if ($imgRight != false && in_array(1, $imgRight)) { 
      $chk =  'checked="checked"' } 
   else { $chk = '';}
}
```

and in your checkbox element just do

```
echo $chk;
```

Comment: Try searching for short tags (not shortcode, sorry for that) and deprecated and you'll see. I know that it's not really 100% true as it was just an idea of the dev team and they decided not to do it...for now! But it might happen one day...if you do some further research, you'll also find that there are few other reasons not to use them - see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019696/what-is-the-difference-between-the-php-open-tags-and-php)

Comment: Ah yes, there has been talk about that. I thought you were referring to the ternary operator, since there were no short tags in the OP's question.