# Apart from it being lazy is there a good reason not use <?= to echo PHP variables?

Tags: php, lazy-evaluation, shorthand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the PHP open tags “<?=” and “<?php”/“<?”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019696/what-is-the-difference-between-the-php-open-tags-and-php)

Rather than type:

```
<?php echo $foo; ?>
```

I have seen it written

```
<?= $foo; ?>
```

But I've often wondered what the risk/impracticalities are of doing it? Just curious. Thanks!

Comment: You can actually skip the semicolon in the second style, too.

Comment: @ceejayoz you can skip it in the first style as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to move the code to an environment where `short_open_tag` isn't enabled, you'll be exposing a lot of internal variable names (security issue) and have a whole lot of damaged output.

The other downside is that the same setting that allows usage of `<?=` is the same that lets you open PHP tags with just `<?`, so having it disabled would not only expose those specific variables you were attempting to display, but also display any PHP code within short tags.

Comment: In PHP5.4 and up, `<?=` syntax is **always** available.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting to know.  I'll have to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The second option increases the readability. The first ensures portability to other systems.

Other than that, there is no difference at all...

Answer (score 1):

It's not portable. There's a pre-5.4 configuration setting to turn it off, so if you move your script to a site where it is disabled, it would break

Also, it's less explicit in my opinion. The difference between `<?= func() ?>` and `<? func(); ?>` is easy to miss, but important

Comment: In PHP5.4 and up, `<?=` syntax is **always** available.

Comment: Exactly right. Also applies to all of those shortened <? tags. I always use <?php just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `<?` and `<?=` if short tags are enabled when you are running PHP.  The actual reason not to use it is because it's incompatible with an xml declaration.  If you are trying to output xml with a php extension and you have short tags enabled, you have to do something like `<<??>?` .. I suppose you can just echo a string.

Comment: This was the reason I once heard actually, but couldn't quite recall what effect it had.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand all that portability talk.

There is ALWAYS a portability issue.
There can be no apache - so, don't use mod_rewrite.
There can be no PDO - so, don't use prepared statements.
There can be no mysql - so, don't use complex queries.
There can be no PHP - so, **plain HTML is most compatible format**, never use anything else because of portability issues!

Comment: If I could accomplish everything I needed to do without using php, and by only typing 7 extra characters, you bet I would! The thing with portability is that it's always a tradeoff.  In the case of short tags, the extra work is so trivial that it makes it a no-brained, IMO

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Not the same. If there's no php, install it. If you want to start using xml or move your php scripts to a server that uses it, you have a lot of rewriting to do...

Comment: @Dennis WHAT? "start using XML"? I am using it all the way. What's wrong with XML?