# What's the difference in using <?php ... ?> and <? ... ?>

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the PHP open tags “<?=” and “<?php”/“<?”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019696/what-is-the-difference-between-the-php-open-tags-and-php)

Does it make any difference when using

```
<?php
    something;
    something2;
?>
```

and

```
<?
    something;
    something2;
?>
```

Everywhere I see `<?php ... ?>` is used. Does it have any advantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not use** `<? ... ?>` and you will never have an issue.

Google `php shorthand`.

Answer (score 1):

`<?` requires that short tags be enabled on the server. It conflicts with some other directives (such as `<?xml`).

Answer (score 1):

Second option works only if `short_open_tag` is enabled.

Besides, if it's enabled, than you can't use php inside XML, where `<?xml ...>` is sometime used.