# Changing PHP Short tags

Tags: php

So I have the following line...

```
<?=$variable?>
```

Is there a way to change it to long tags without typing a full echo statement?

`<?php=$variable?>` doesn't work

I know that `<?php echo $variable ?>` will work, but is there a shorter way to do it?

Comment: discussion on why echo is better ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to change it to long tags without typing a full echo statement?

No

Edit: For Strager http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27448&edit=1

Answer (score 2):

The shorter way is to use tokenized replacements (via a templating system, [like Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)) instead of interpolating between php and html syntax.  Tokens are cleaner in general, and [they don't have to be complicated](http://code.google.com/p/bmcore/source/browse/classes/page.php).

Your HTML would look like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>%title_token%</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">%content_token%</div>
    <div id="footer">%footer_token%</div>
</body>
</html>
```

etc.  Different templating systems use different tokens (Smarty uses a several-step define, parse, compile), but all you really need is [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace($template, '%title_token%', 'Super Awesome Webpage');
```

Comment: PHP is faster.  Always.  And PHP doesn't need much learning, because you already know it.  (I can't say much for designers, however.)

Comment: +1 for Smarty. Some people love it, others seem to avoid at all costs. To each his own :)

Comment: @strager By "faster" I meant "takes less time to write / read", but changed to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

What?

The short way to do it is `<?= ... ?>`. Which is equivalent to `<?php echo ... ?>`.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Wait, so do PHP short tags need to be turned on for <?= ... ?> ?  I'm trying to avoid short tags is all.

Comment: Yes, short tags includes all variants of `<?` without `php`

Comment: @Mike B, `asp_tags` allows for `<%` and `<%=`, which mimic `<?` and `<?=`, respectively.

Comment: @strager that's entirely irrelevant, nobody's even asking about asp style tags.

Comment: @strager asp style tags != short tags. The asker said he was trying to avoid short tags. I assume he would also want to avoid the very rare asp tags as well.

Comment: @Mike B, The statement "short tags includes all variants of `<?` without `php`" is incorrect.  Sorry I wasn't being clear in stating that.

Comment: @strager Can you expand on that? What short tag consists of `<?` and `php`?

Comment: @Mike B, A 'variant of `<?` without `php`' is `<%`.  `<%` is not included in `short_tags`; it is included in `asp_tags`.

Comment: @strager But I said said variants of short tags (which is really `<? ?>` and `<?= ?>`), not all possible php tags. ASP tags are not inclusive in short tags AFAIK.

Comment: @Mike B, You said "variants of `<?`", not "variants of short tags".  Also, there are either no "variants of short tags", or there are, and the only variants in PHP I see are `<%` and `<%=`.

Comment: @strager I think we're talking about two different things :p. My lack of decent grammar is probably my flaw. I'll just leave it at that since the significance of this discussion is rather unimportant. See you around SO!