# difference <?php echo '$test'; ?> and <?=$test?>

Tags: php

What is the difference between

```
<?php echo '$test'; ?>
```

and

```
<?=$test?>
```

?

Comment: I think you meant <?php echo $test; ?> and <?=$test?>

Comment: @Justin: Most probably. Could someone please close this question?

Comment: @polemon - Mention the duplicate / reason if you think it should be closed.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you really meant `<?php echo $test; ?>`, the two are effectively the same thing. The question is, how portable do you want to be. `<?php ?>` is supported just about anywhere that PHP is supported, however lots of admins disable `<?= ?>` syntax.

Answer (score 8):

The former outputs the literal string `$test` and the latter outputs the value `$test`.

Comment: If you have short tags turned on.

Answer (score 3):

`<?= $test ?>` is identical to `<?php echo $test; ?>`

Since PHP 5.4.0 this `<?= ... ?>` tag is always available regardless of php.ini settings on short tags, and **short_open_tag** directive only [controls](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) `<? ... ?>` tag.

Also, [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags).

It is generally advised not to use short tags, but it is handy to use them only for simple outputs in templates with longer version only used for more complicated logic. That makes PHP code which tends to be messy more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the `<?= ?>`, which is called `short_open_tags`, for templates or the "view" portion of my scripts. But this does have to explicitly be  enabled in the php.ini so if you are working on a script for distribution it is best to avoid using it, unless you do not care if the buyers / users of the script may not have `short_open_tags` turned on.

Comment: Also, enabling `short_open_tags` enables the use of `<? ... ?>` instead of `<?php ... ?>` which can have unexpected side effects as PHP is not the only one to use the tag with question mark format (for one thing, a valid XHTML page should have an xml tag at the beginning, which looks like `<?xml ... ?>`).