# How can I pass a PHP variable to javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, session, parameter-passing

I want to use a PHP variable as a javascript variable - specifically I want to user the PHP variable session_id(); and use this as a javascript variable.

```
<?php
$php_var = session_id();
?>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
js_var = <?php echo($php_var ?>;
</script>
```

This seems like it should work for me but it doesnt can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: duplicate. [please use the search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+can+I+pass+a+PHP+variable+to+javascript%3F).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best method i can think of looks like this:

```
<?php
$php_var = session_id();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var js_var = <?php echo json_encode($php_var); ?>;
</script>
```

PHP's `json_encode`-function is always producing valid JavaScript, which is not ensured if you are simply outputting random values. If you decide not to use `json_encode()`, you should at least enclose the php-value with quotes to prevent syntax errors. Be aware of escaping!

```
<?php
$php_var = session_id();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var js_var = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for `json_encode`. That's what it's there for. Don't ever use the raw-echo version. You risk bugs and XSS security holes.

Comment: What do you mean by "Be aware of escaping!"?  You don't seem to escape anything in your code example....?  Thanks!

Comment: @JDelage: My first example escapes everything properly (that is what `json_encode()` does while serializing). The second example does not. That is why I recommend using the first technique. The second technique is only ever usable when dealing with already-escaped values or values that are impossible to cause invalid JavaScript, but it really does not make a lot of sense to use, since the first one covers all cases.

Answer (score 3):

That's just fine. Be sure that if the variable you're echoing is a string that you put quotes around it and escape any quotes, newlines, etc. inside it -- e.g., make sure it really gets output as a valid JavaScript string literal. Also, don't forget the `var` before `js_var`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have opened a parenthesis in the `echo` call, but didn't close it.
Also, you should place a semicolon after it. You've also forgotten the quotes (as Gordon says in the comment below).

```
<?php
$php_var = session_id();
?>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
js_var = "<?php echo($php_var); ?>";
</script>
```

<s>P.S.You can use less code by replacing `echo` with the '=' character:</s>

```
js_var="<?=$php_var?>";
```

Comment: Funny how people upvote this answer the most although it misses the quotes around the php block and advertises using the shorthand syntax, which is [widely regarded as bad practise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags/1386631#1386631).

Comment: I didn't know that using the shorthand syntax is bad... thanks for the link. And you're right about the quotes... I've already changed it. I don't really know why did I forget about them...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because your snippet contains errors, it should be:

```
<?php
$php_var = session_id();
?>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
js_var = <?php echo $php_var ?>;
</script>
```