# mixing javascript and php variables in ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a pretty basic jQuery ajax thing happening, but I want to mix form data that is retrieved by JS with some PHP variables and have them all sent as part of the ajax GET. Should this work?:

```
var longform = $("input:text").serialize(); 
$.ajax({
    url:    'actions/create.php',
    data:   longform + "domain=<?php echo $domain; ?>&useragent=<?php echo $useragent; ?>&ip=<?php echo $ip; ?>&cookieuser=<?php echo $cookieuser; ?>",
```

Currently, when create.php tries to echo the variables back, they're empty.

**UPDATE**

After checking the source as suggested, it comes out like this:

```
data:   longform + "&domain=example.com&useragent=Mozilla/5.0
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658027/how-can-i-pass-a-php-variable-to-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather put all data in hidden inputs, and then serialize all in once.

Tom

Comment: Yes, I decided to go this route.. turns out my main problem was a dumb mistake on my part.. missed a $_GET in the php >_>

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ampersand (&) before *domain=*.  Otherwise, it should be fine.

Do a *View Source* on the page and make sure the javascript string looks correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

Everything should be fine if you add PHP's [`urlencode()`-function](http://php.net/urlencode):

```
"domain=<?php echo urlencode($domain); ?>&useragent=<?php echo urlencode($useragent); ?>&ip=<?php echo urlencode($ip); ?>&cookieuser=<?php echo urlencode($cookieuser); ?>"
```

This should prevent syntax errors that could be caused by your data (i.e. if you have backslashes or other special chars in there).