# Skip the "echo"; just let me see my variable

Tags: php, echo

In .net we've got the following to write a variable (well, it's ToString() method) in an asp.net page:

```
<%= myString %>
```

Is there anything like this in php? (I'm tired of typing "ehco" instead of "echo");

Comment: It's an extremely bad practice to do such thing. It's not valid on every environment, you'll find yourself having more problems than answers. Type the whole echo, it takes 1 second and may save you many hours of debugging.

Comment: @Vincent but have you ever seen a server where they've been disabled? I mean, in the real world? I avoid short open tags for the same reason as you, but I find myself asking whether it's really a problem to use them.

Comment: most IDEs allow you to make macros of some sort: make a macro that echos 'echo'.

Comment: @Pekka: Yes, way too often. I post on another forum (mostly for beginners), and we have to answer this question a few times every week because they don't understand why it doesn't work. As zzzzBov suggested, I'd definitely use a macro that converts <?= to <?php echo.

Comment: @Pekka I've never used a server where short-tags were enabled by default. I could always change that, but why would I? I'm not *that* lazy.

Comment: @Vincent okay; I for one have never seen  a server where short open tags were disabled. I'm seriously thinking about returning to them - the macro idea is certainly the best way to go about it though

Comment: extremely is pretty extreme, man. The "not being valid on every environment" argument is kinda a lame, IMO. If the shorthand isn't going to work in my environment then clearly I'm not in control of that environment...so I don't really care (in this instance).

Comment: @Vincent It is arguably *mildly* bad practice *at worst*. "Extremely bad practice" is your own spin. Many people continue to use them, and there is *absolutely* no reason to avoid using them in your output-oriented templates. "Some servers might not have them" is a completely bogus reason. Some servers might not have GD, or cURL, or any one of countless optional PHP features. You don't avoid those features, you use them and then choose a host which provides them.

Comment: @David and meagar : I'm not gonna argue forever, this is based on my own experience and I'm not going to haunt you if you use short tags. With today's IDEs, you can easily make a macro that replaces <?= to <?php echo and I don't see any reason not to use it. Okay, maybe "extremely" was a bit overkill, though :-p

Comment: @Vincent Readable code is *far* more important than saving keystrokes. I find `<?= $name ?>` far more readable than `<?php echo $name ?>`, especially when mixed with HTML. Using a macro misses the point entirely.

Comment: @meagar : I don't. This is subjective, I'm talking about real impact short tags have on code (i.e. may not always work). [troll]If we go about more readable code, might as well drop PHP for Python![/troll]

Comment: @Vincent As I said above, "may not always work" is a bogus argument. `mod_rewrite` doesn't work everywhere, neither does MySQL. Are you recommending that people avoid those? If you only use features that are universally available, you'll be writing in PHP3 forever.

Comment: @meagar : I really don't understand what this have to do with anything, therefore I'll stop answering to you. I really stated my points, so did you, this is going nowhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided you have `short_open_tags` enabled in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), you can use:

```
<?= $myString ?>
```

[Debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags) [rages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413661/php6-is-short-open-tag-removed-or-deprecated-or-neither) about whether this is a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use).

It is also possible to use ASP-style tags by enabling `asp_tags` in php.ini, but they are *not recommended* (read, deprecated and I believe being [removed in PHP6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533194/php-short-tags-really-being-deprecated-in-php6-closed)):

```
<%= $myString %>
```

Comment: It's not deprecated and will [not be removed in PHP 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533194/php-short-tags-really-being-deprecated-in-php6-closed). But it's correct it's not recommended

Comment: @Pekka I was talking specifically about ASP-style tags, not short_open_tag

Comment: I will add as a comment (to leave my answer slightly more neutral) that I personal believe `short_open_tags` are amazingly useful, and the only reason I'd consider PHP as a template langauge. `<?php echo $name ?>` is hideous, and I will *never* use it in my templates.

Comment: You just saved me from having to type out 22 `<?php echos ` (or "ehcos" as I keep typing).

Answer (score 3):

`<?= $var ?>` will do it.

Comment: so, I would mark this as accepted because you answered 9 seconds faster...but meagar told me how to turn it on...which i needed. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

`<?= $myString ?>` (assuming PHP's short tags are enabled)