# Is it possible to stop Zend Studio from formatting embedded PHP like this?

Tags: php, html, code-formatting, zend-studio

I want to upgrade to Zend Studio (currently using Netbeans), but I am slightly disappointed about how the formatter formats PHP in HTML attributes. Given this:

```
<tr bgcolor="<?php echo "red"; ?>">
```

Zend Studio will format it similar to this:

```
<tr bgcolor="<?php
echo "red";
?>">
```

Has anyone been able to change this behavior? Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using?

```
<tr bgcolor="<?= "red" ?>">
```

Comment: No way! It worked. Thank you so much! I've never seen that syntax before. I'm assuming it's supposed to be inline?

Comment: Oh, wait I see. `<?=` means `<?php echo`

Comment: Changing your writing syntax because your formatter isn't working correctly isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Few comments about the pros and cons of short tags here: [PHP echo vs PHP short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags)

Slightly off topic but I recommend you use CSS not bgcolour for your colours etc.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I do use CSS, but I was feeling lazy so I ripped that snippet from the example project that comes with Zend Studio... so shame on them! ;)