# How can i use appendstylesheet in template file?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using zend for my project. I am having code like below inside `<HEAD>`,

```
    <?=  $this->headLink()
        ->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/css.css') 
        ->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/front.css') 
        ->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/jquerymenu.css')
        ->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/lider.css'); ?>
```

In my template page say list.phtml has the code like ,

```
<?=  $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/templates/list.css');  ?>
```

So this append style sheet twice,

```
1. Inside <HEAD> tag
2. Inside that list.phtml.
```

How do i include only inside `<HEAD>` tag in zend ? or Is it possible to apply this list.css only when user open list page?
By doing this we can pass w3 validation.Kindly advice on this ?

Comment: @AwaisQarni i did not get you. i want to apply list.css only when user open list.phtml file.how can i do here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shorttag `<?=` equals `<?php echo`. So in your viewtemplate just use

```
<?php  $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(BASE_URL . 'css/templates/list.css');  ?>
```

This will add the `list.css` and it will echoed together with the other stylesheets in your layout template when you call the `headLink()`.

To make sure that your base CSS is the first loaded you can use `prependStylesheet()`.

Also consider *not* to use shorttags, see [this question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags) info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the `<?=` tag, which is equivalent to write the following:

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet(...); ?>
```

Replace the `<?=` with `<?php` and you shouldn't have it displayed twice.

Hope that helps,