# If/Else statement in onclick functions

Tags: php, javascript

I have this `onclick` function and it is working fine:

```
onclick="transferplayer('palyerlistDIVID','<?=$d_player['id']?>',document.getElementById('play perPosition').value,'teamID','plus','<?=$d_player['teamID']?>','<?=$d_player['price']?>');showmyplayer('myplayerlistDIVID',document.getElementById('playperPosition').value,'plus','<?=$d_player['teamID']?>','<?=$d_player['price']?>')"
```

What I need is to set a time between clicks, so I added this javascript with 5 seconds between each click:

```
var lastClicked = 0;

function onClickCheck() {
    var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (timeNow > (lastClicked + 5000)) {
        // Execute the link action 
    } else {
        alert('Please wait at least 5 seconds between clicks!');
    }
    lastClicked = timeNow;
}
```

The question is: how can I combine this code with `onclick` functions?

I tried this:

```
onclick="onClickCheck();transferplayer('palyerlistDIVID','<?=$d_player['id']?>',document.getElementById('play perPosition').value,'teamID','plus','<?=$d_player['teamID']?>','<?=$d_player['price']?>');showmyplayer('myplayerlistDIVID',document.getElementById('playperPosition').value,'plus','<?=$d_player['teamID']?>','<?=$d_player['price']?>')"
```

But on clicking it takes the values always.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the `transferplayer` call into your if clause.

```
onclick="onClickCheck()"


function onClickCheck() {
    var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (timeNow > (lastClicked + 5000)) {
        transferplayer('palyerlistDIVID','<?=$d_player['id']?>',
                        document.getElementById('playerPosition').value,
                        'teamID',
                        'plus',
                        '<?=$d_player['teamID']?>',
                        '<?=$d_player['price']?>');

         showmyplayer('myplayerlistDIVID',
                      document.getElementById('playperPosition').value, 
                      'plus',
                      '<?=$d_player['teamID']?>',
                      '<?=$d_player['price']?>');
    } else {
        alert('Please wait at least 5 seconds between clicks!');
    }
    lastClicked = timeNow;
}
```

And, for the record, use of PHP short tags is not recommended.  See [PHP echo vs PHP short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags) for a discussion of the subject.

Comment: About the short tags... I agree when <? is used, but <?= is completly ok, even php 5.4. advices the use > http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php (<?= is now always available, regardless of the short_open_tag php.ini option.)

Answer (score 2):

It is not advisable to use inline javascript. You should try to bind the click on that element.

But your answer:

```
onclick="var lastClicked = 0;if(timeNow>(lastClicked + 5000)){ var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime(); if (timeNow > (lastClicked + 5000)) { transferplayer('palyerlistDIVID','<?=$d_player['id']?>',document.getElementById('play perPosition').value,'teamID','plus','<?=$d_player['teamID']?>','<?=$d_player['price']?>');showmyplayer('myplayerlistDIVID',document.getElementById('playperPosition').value,'plus','<?=$d_player['teamID']?>','<?=$d_player['price']?>'); }else{ alert('Please wait at least 5 seconds between clicks!'); } lastClicked = timeNow;"
```

Comment: Why not move this all into a function?