# HTML showing PHP code written in value area

Tags: php, html

I have this HTML code. It is supposed to be a register form. It is using a Session to store the information in case something is wrong so that the user doesn't have to re-enter the information again. But somehow, it is writing the whole PHP code inside the value part. Yes it is in the format .php and I am using WAMP Server. I also tried to use APPServ but to no avail. Here is the code

```
 <form action="register.php" method="post">
    <h1>Register Form</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Login name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="login_name" value="<?=(!empty($_POST['login_name'])) ? $_POST['login_name'] : ''?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?=(!empty($_POST['first_name'])) ? $_POST['first_name'] : ''?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?=(!empty($_POST['last_name'])) ? $_POST['last_name'] : ''?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pw1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pw2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?=(!empty($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : ''?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Register!" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The only problem I'm having is what I mentioned: The textboxes show the PHP code I wrote in the value part. Everything else is working fine. I am using Chrome in Window 8. I should also note that I sent this code to a friend and it worked just fine and the only difference we have is that he is using Windows 7.

Comment: [Short tags aren't enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Comment: Try changing `<?=` to `<?php echo`

Comment: Wow thank you so much. This was actually the solution. I don't understand though, why did it work for my friend but not for me. Either way thanks! I'll make sure to choose your answer if you post it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags'

Comment: I just read about that. I didn't see the first answer :3 Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<?=` is short form of `<?php echo`. In WAMP Server, short tags are off by default. You can solve this problem in two ways :

1. Change `<?=`  to `<?php echo`

   OR
2. Find php.ini file in wamp folder and change `short_open_tag = On`

Answer (score 0):

replace the  `<?=` to `<?php`