# How to pass a IRL variable to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass a URL variable to an alert box which pops up as soon as the page loads.

The URL looks like `http://www.example.com/?state=california`.

I've already put the PHP code on top of my code to get the variable-

```
<?php 
$state = $_GET['state'];  
?>
```

And my alert box looks like this--it's placed in the head section.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
alert('Warning!\n\nPlease confirm you are from [the state variable here!]');
});
</script>
```

Generally in PHP I'd put `<?=$state?>` but obviously it doesn't work in JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want to get the GET variables in javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid use of php short open tags which may not be enabled in your version..[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags) for more

```
<?php 
   $state = $_GET['state'];  
?>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     alert('Warning!\n\nPlease confirm you are from <?php echo $state;?>');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `$state = "I'm a string that will cause some troubles"`

Answer (score 1):

PHP short open tag are always not enabled in the system, so better to use `<?php ...?>`

And don't forget to escape the string as it can contain special characters i.e **single quotes** and **double quotes**, that can terminate with unexpected error.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('Warning!\n\nPlease confirm you are from ' + '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["state"])?>');
    });
</script>
```

Refer [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the state from the URL using pure JavaScript.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var query = document.location.search, // get the query string from the URL
  state = /[&?]state=([^&]*)/.exec(query)[1]; // get the state using regex
  alert('Warning!\n\nPlease confirm you are from ' + state);
});
</script>
```

- With the example URL of `http://www.example.com/?state=california`, `document.location.search` will return `?state=california`.
- `/[&?]state=([^&]*)/` is a regular expression literal. This regular expression looks for a `?` or `&` followed by `state=` and then captures everything after that until it hits a `&` or the end of the string.
- Using the [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method of the RegExp literal will run the regular expression against the provided string. `.exec` returns an array, the first element (index`0`) is the entire matched string `'?state=california'`, the second element (index `1`) is just the part between the capture parentheses, `'california'`. The `[1]` on the end of the statement grabs the item from that array with the index `1`, thus storing `'california'` in the `state` variable.

This should work for simple one word values as in your case. If you needed to support longer strings with spaces an non-alphanumeric characters, before you display the string do this:

```
state = decodeURIComponent(state).replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

[`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) will decode url encoded characters and `replace` will replace the any `+` in the url with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Well, exactly this works in JavaScript BUT! When the page is fully loaded the connection to the server is closed and you have no more access to PHP variables.

You have to place the variable while the page loads fully the first time.

If the content of the variable should change after some button clicks or any interactive action on the page is done you cannot gather and update any information from PHP without doing an AJAX request (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

You should be fine with this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('Warning!\n\nPlease confirm you are from ' + '<?=$_GET["state"]?>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This approach causes XSS problems, `$_GET["state"]` needs to be escaped: `htmlspecialchars($_GET["state"])`

Answer (score -1):

use `addslashes` and echo.

`addslashes` will avoid your code to break if state name has `quotes` in it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<?php
   $state = $_GET['state'];
?>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     alert('Warning!\n\nPlease confirm you are from <?php echo addslashes($state); ?>');
  });
</script>
```