# Google chart is not working on server side

Tags: php, html, google-visualization, datetimepicker

I have a view that shows a chart depending on a date time range and one value from select list, it is currently working perfect in my local, but in my server it just dont chart anything, can anyone help me pls.

Here is the view code:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Gráfico</title>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
     href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      //Funcion para generar un gráfico en Lineas
      function LineChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?= $grafico2;?>);
        var options = {
          title: '<?php echo "Paquetes recibidos por la IP: ".$ip." en las fechas: ".$fechainicio." - ".$fechafin; ?>',
          'width':900,
          'height':400,
          hAxis: {title: 'Fechas',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'},},
          vAxis: {title: 'Paquetes',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'},}
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(LineChart); 
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <div id="contenido">
    <div class="container">     
    <?php include_once "header.php"; ?>
     <?php echo form_open('home/graph'); ?>
    <font color="#27A7D6">Seleccione fecha inicial:<br></font>
    <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
      <input type="text" name="fechainicio"></input>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-date-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.11.0.js">
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.es.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'es'
      });
    </script>

<font color="#27A7D6">Seleccione fecha final:<br></font>

 <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append date">
      <input type="text" name="fechafin"></input>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-date-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.11.0.js">
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.es.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'es'
      });
    </script>
    <!-- INICIO DEL SELECT IP-->
    <?php
require_once ('funciones.php');
$con=fullconectar();
$res=mysql_query("select * from alarmas",$con);
?>
<font color="#27A7D6">Seleccione su IP:<br></font>
<select id="ip" name ="ip" style="width:235px">
<?php while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>
<option><?php echo $fila['ip']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<div><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php echo "Total de tiempo offline para la IP: ".$ip." entre las fechas: ".$fechainicio." - ".$fechafin.": ".$tiempooff." minutos."; ?>
    <div id="linechart_div"></div>
</div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should provide us a link to the live version in a case like this, because the most likely scenario is that some of your library links are broken, but you can't tell that from your PHP file.

Comment: Sure mate: http://www.syscomlatam.com/GSS/index.php/home/graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the actual output, the problematic line is here:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?= $grafico2;?>);
```

You'll notice that the `<?= $grafico2;?>` didn't get parsed by your PHP engine. This indicates that you don't have short-tags enabled on your server. For the moment, just swich that line to:

`var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $grafico2;?>);`

But you'll probably want to [enable short-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags) for the future.