# PHP javascript function...simpler way?

Tags: javascript, php

The javascript countdown code I am using requires me to use this format: "year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second". I have the following code, which works, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler method of getting it to work (one with less lines, one that might be quicker?)

```
$year = date('Y',$date);
$month = date('n',$date);
$day = date('j',$date);
$hour = date('g',$date);
$minute = date('i',$date);
$second = date('s',$date);
$js .= "var newYear = new Date();
        newYear = new Date(".$year.", ".$month." - 1, ".$day.", ".$hour.", ".$minute.", ".$second.");
        $('#timer').countdown({
            until: newYear,
            layout: '{hn} h {mn} m {sn} s'
        });";
```

Comment: none of the php is needed, js has date functions to

Comment: @Dagon Well, *some* PHP is needed, to transport the variable `$date`, which has presumably been calculated elsewhere, into an appropriate JS value.

Comment: Using the `date` function six times and then concocting the results is unnecessary, to do it all with one `date` function call: `date("Y, n, y, g, i, s", $date)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid generating Javascript via PHP. Your Javascript code should not change per-user or per page render, and you should simply include it from a static file. Any *data* should be accessed over Ajax or stored locally in that page via a DOM node:

```
<input type="hidden" id="someAppData" value="1242525242"/>
$(function () {
    // Grab the data from the DOM node
    var newYear = $('#someAppData').val();

    $('#timer').countdown({
        until: newYear,
        layout: '{hn} h {mn} m {sn} s'
    });
});
```

Comment: This way you can include an external JS file and not have to worry about making your web server parse `.js` files with the PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any PHP code for this besides passing along the `$date` value to your HTML page. Consider passing over a timestamp value.

HTML/(PHP >5.2.0) Code:

```
<script>
    var newYear = new Date(<?= (new DateTime($date))->getTimestamp() * 1000 ?>);
    $('#timer').countdown({
        until: newYear,
        layout: '{hn} h {mn} m {sn} s'
    });";
</script>
```

Basically you're passing over the timestamp from PHP (in seconds) to your Javascript (in milliseconds) into their respective Date objects. If you don't have [short tags enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags), you can replace what's in the angle brackets with `<?php echo (new DateTime($date))->getTimestamp() * 1000; ?>`

Comment: Why `(new DateTime($date))->getTimestamp() * 1000` when you could just do `time()*1000`?

Comment: OP didn't ask for current time. This could be a value that's been passed in through a form or query string.

Comment: `strtotime($date)` then ;)

Comment: Whiehever, I figure that this would be most accurate, and respective to timezones if done right.