# submit button is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to the Codeigniter.

The thing is, the form is not working. There is no error while displaying the page; but I do not know why it is not working. Guys, please help me.

This is my serarch_view.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> `Insert Data Into Database Using CodeIgniter Form</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus'                  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>`
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?  >css/style.css" />
</head>
  <body>
      <div id="container">

     <? echo form_open('insert_ctrl');?>
         <h1>Insert Data Into Database Using CodeIgniter</h1><hr/>
        <?php echo form_label('Search book according to :'); ?>  <br />
        <?php echo form_dropdown('dsearch',$options); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dname', 'name' => 'dname')); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>

        <?php echo form_close(); ?><br/>


       </div>

</body>
```

This is my view insert_view.php

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Insert Data Into Database Using CodeIgniter Form</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus'            rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
       <? echo form_open('insert_ctrl/insert');?>
        <h1>Insert Data  </h1><hr/> 
        <?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
            <CENTER><h3 style="color:green;">Data inserted successfully</h3></CENTER><br>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php echo form_label('isbn :'); ?>  <?php echo form_error('disbn'); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'disbn', 'name' => 'disbn')); ?><br />

        <?php echo form_label('Title :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dtitle'); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dtitle', 'name' => 'dtitle')); ?><br />

        <?php echo form_label('Subject :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dsubject'); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dsubject', 'name' => 'dsubject')); ?><br />

        <?php echo form_label('Category:'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dcategory'); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dcategory', 'name' => 'dcategory')); ?><br />

        <?php echo form_label('Author'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dauthor'); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dauthor', 'name' => 'dauthor')); ?><br />

         <?php echo form_label('Edition'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dedition'); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dedition', 'name' => 'dedition')); ?><br />

         <?php echo form_label('Publisher'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dpublisher'); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dpublisher', 'name' => 'dpublisher')); ?><br />

         <?php echo form_label('Copy :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dcopy'); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dcopy', 'name' => 'dcopy')); ?><br />

         <?php echo form_label('Book Position:'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dbook_position'); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dcbook_position', 'name' => 'dbook_position')); ?><br />

         <?php echo form_label('Shelf Number :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dshelf_number'); ?><br />
        <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'dshelf_number', 'name' => 'dshelf_number')); ?><br />

        <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>

        <?php echo form_close(); ?><br/>

       <div id="fugo">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my controller insert_ctrl.php

```
  <?php
class Insert_ctrl extends CI_Controller {


function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('insert_model');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    //$this->load->view('insert_view');
}

function search() {


              $data1['options']=array(
                    'titlewisesearch'=>'Title wise search',
                    'authorwisesearch'=>'Author wise search',
                    'isbnwisesearch'=>'ISBN wise search',
                    'subjectwisesearch'=>'Subject wise search',
                    );
             $this->load->view('search_view',$data1);
             //Setting values for tabel columns



            $data['name'] = $this->input->post('dname');
            $data['dsearch']=$this->input->post('dsearch'); 

            $name=$data['name'];
            $dsearch=$data['dsearch'];

            //'return_date' => $this->input->post('dreturn_date'),
            //'return_type' => $this->input->post('dreturn_type')

            switch($dsearch)
            {
                case "titlewisesearch":$data['title_search']=$this->insert_model->search_title($name);
                                                $title_search=$data['title_search'];
                                                 if(!empty($title_search))
                                                 {
                                                   foreach($title_search as $r)
                                                     {
                                                      echo $r;
                                                      }
                                                   }
                                                   else
                                                   echo "Enter the values";
                                            break;
                case "isbnwisesearch":$data['isbn_search']=$this->insert_model->search_isbn($name);
                                              $isbn_search=$data['isbn_search'];
                                               if(!empty($isbn_search))
                                                 {
                                             foreach($isbn_search as $r)
                                                {
                                                echo $r;
                                                }
                                                 }
                                                 else
                                                   echo "Enter the values";
                                              break;
                case "authorwisesearch":$data['author_search']=$this->insert_model->search_author($name);
                                              $author_search=$data['author_search'];
                                               if(!empty($author_search)) 
                                               {
                                              foreach($author_search as $r)
                                                {
                                                echo $r;
                                                }
                                               }
                                                else
                                                   echo "Enter the values";
                                          break;
                case "subjectwisesearch":$data['subject_search']=$this->insert_model->search_subject($name);
                                               $subject_search=$data['subject_search'];
                                                if(!empty($subject_search)) 
                                               {
                                              foreach($subject_search as $r)
                                                {
                                                echo $r;
                                                }
                                                }
                                                else
                                                   echo "Enter the values";
                                          break;
            }


        //Transfering data to Model


         }



function insert() {
    //Including validation library
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('disbn', 'ISBN', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[50]');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dtitle', 'Title', 'required');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dsubject', 'Subject', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dcategory', 'Title', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dauthor', 'Author', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dedition', 'Edition', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dpublisher', 'Publisher', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dcopy', 'Copy', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dbook_position', 'Book position', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dshelf_number', 'Shelf number', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('insert_view');
    } else {
        //Setting values for tabel columns
        $data = array(
            'isbn' => $this->input->post('disbn'),
            'title' => $this->input->post('dtitle'),
            'subject' => $this->input->post('dsubject'),
            'category'=> $this->input->post('dcategory'),
            'author' => $this->input->post('dauthor'),
            'edition' => $this->input->post('dedition'),
            'publisher' => $this->input->post('dpublisher'),
            'copy' => $this->input->post('dcopy'),
            'book_position' => $this->input->post('dbook_position'),
            'shelf_number' => $this->input->post('dshelf_number')
             );
        //Transfering data to Model
        $this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
        $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
        //Loading View
        $this->load->view('insert_view', $data);
    }
}            



}


 ?>
```

This is my insert_model.php

```
<?php

class insert_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
     $this->load->database();
}

}


function search_isbn($isbn){
$this->db->select('title');
$this->db->from('add_book');
$this->db->where('isbn', $isbn); 
$query = $this->db->get();
if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    $row = $query->row_array();
    return $row;
}



 }

 function search_author($author){
$this->db->select('title');
$this->db->from('add_book');
$this->db->where('author', $author); 
$query = $this->db->get();
if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    $row = $query->row_array();
    return $row;
}


 }


 function search_subject($subject){
$this->db->select('title');
$this->db->from('add_book');
$this->db->where('subject',$subject); 
$query = $this->db->get();
if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    $row = $query->row_array();
    return $row;
}
 }
 function form_insert($data){`//Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college) 
   $this->db->insert('add_book', $data);  
}    
 }  
?>
```

Comment: The submit button is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `<? echo form_open('insert_ctrl');?>` by `<?php echo form_open('insert_ctrl');?>`

This may by cause of your sort tag.

Comment: what is the difference between these too ..?

Comment: See this link http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php   , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you then please mark as right answer and vote up :)

Comment: page not found y is it so ...?

Comment: check you page name with your controller method. are both same?

Comment: i dont hve  index function in my controller file does it affect ...?can u pls check it ...

Comment: in your first form your url is just `insert_ctrl` which goes to your index function.