# show name of user when he/she login PHP

Tags: php

As I said in title, I want when user login site, some where show name of him/her. So I have a welcome page as this:

```
<body>
<div id='fg_membersite_content'>
<h2>Home Page</h2>
Welcome back <?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>! 
</body>
```

and `fg_membersite` has a function like this:

```
function UserFullName()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
}
```

and also there is another function:

```
function CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }          
    $username = $this->SanitizeForSQL($username);
    $pwdmd5 = md5($password);
    $qry = "Select name, email from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";
    $result =mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");
    $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);

    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $this->HandleError("Error logging in. The username or password does not match");
        return false;
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


    $_SESSION['name_of_user']  = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['email_of_user'] = $row['email'];

    return true;
}
```

but when I run the login page, it just show me:

```
Welcome back UserFullName(); ?>!
```

Comment: Where do you create your class object? If it isn't a class, what is `$fgmembersite`?

Comment: Does your page name have a .php extension or an .html extension?

Comment: If you view the source I think you'll find you have `<?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>` so `<?= $fgmembersite->` is being treated as an element. So you are using PHP on an HTML page.

Comment: @Script47 fg_membersite is a page contain the functions

Comment: @chris85: can u please take a look on this site? http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-registration-form.html

Comment: @user2182349: this is a php page. i've solved most of the problems but i cant understand where is problem

Comment: What am I looking at there? Change the extension from `.htm` to `.php`.  You also should use a more upto date tutorial. Any tutorial using `mysql_` functions is out of date.

Comment: Are PHP short-tags enabled?

Comment: @chris85 but that is a php file, on that site is my source code that i used

Comment: @user2182349 good point,  `Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php What PHP version are you running?

Comment: @user2182349: you are a great man! it fixed!!!! thanks bro thanks please :) should i also remove ';' before short_open_tag? or just turn it on??

Comment: @user2182349: please send your solution as answer so i choose your solution :)

Comment: @chris85 where i should check my PHP version?

Comment: You can use, http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php. I don't use short tags for this exact reason (it's only saving you 8 characters). `= ` in place of `php echo`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP echo vs PHP short tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>
```

is using [PHP's short tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) notation, where **<?=** is processed as **<? echo**.

In versions prior to PHP 5.4, short tags are disabled by default and must be enabled by setting *short_open_tag* to *on*.