# Datatables JS get row index by single column value PHP

Tags: javascript, datatables, row, selection

I'm working on a system of medical transportation. Every day I have around 700 trips, so the table is pretty large. 
I want the app, after the user adds a trip, the screen is positioned in the newly added trip. (scroll) ,for the user to corroborate the trip successfully added (not my idea, my client wants it that way) . For this, I am sending to the page by parameter the ID of the new trip added. 
I'm using a function "fnFindCellRowIndexes" that i found on datatables page, but i can't make it work. The column i wait to search in is index 1.
Here's my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var table = $('#tabla').DataTable({
            "deferRender": true,
            "language": {
                "url": "include/DataTables/Spanish.json"
            },
            "paging":   false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info":     false,
            "searching": true,
            "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true
            },
            {
                "targets": [ 1 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
            ],
            "stateSave": true
        }); 

         var index = table.fnFindCellRowIndexes( '<?=$idNuevo?>', 1 );
         alert(index);

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnFindCellRowIndexes = function ( oSettings, sSearch, iColumn )
        {
            var
                i,iLen, j, jLen, val,
                aOut = [], aData,
                columns = oSettings.aoColumns;

            for ( i=0, iLen=oSettings.aoData.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
            {
                aData = oSettings.aoData[i]._aData;

                if ( iColumn === undefined )
                {
                    for ( j=0, jLen=columns.length ; j<jLen ; j++ )
                    {
                        val = this.fnGetData(i, j);

                        if ( val == sSearch )
                        {
                            aOut.push( i );
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (this.fnGetData(i, iColumn) == sSearch )
                {
                    aOut.push( i );
                }
            }

            return aOut;
        };

</script>
```

I'm getting error "fnFindCellRowIndexes is not a function"
Can anyone help me? if anyone has any idea to do it in a better way, suggestions are accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare `fnFindCellRowIndexes` *before* you instantiate your dataTable!
2. You *must* instantiate with `dataTable()`. `fnFindCellRowIndexes` is an oldschool none-API plugin. As far as I can see in your code, you should not have problems with that. If you still want to use the new API, you can always use `table.api().<api-functions>`
3. <strike>The PHP variable does not magically echo itself out (no offense :-) - you forget to actually print it :</strike>

<strike>var index = table.fnFindCellRowIndexes( '<? echo $idNuevo ?>', 1 );</strike>

4. Remember that `fnFindCellRowIndexes` is an equal / == search. If you search for `1` in column #1 it only return columns that hold the value `1` and nothing more, not rows holding `10`, `101`, `1.1` etc.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!! just one comment: <?=$idNuevo?> is exactly the same that <? echo $idNuevo ?>. The '=' before the variable prints it :-)

Comment: @martin.softpro - I honestly didnt knew the `<?= ` shorthand. Apparently there is some [**historical reasons**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php) for its existence, and of course [**semi religous mixed opinions**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-tags) whether to use it or not :) Thank you for pointing me to that discovery :)