# PHP GET parameter

Tags: php, html

I got the index.php file where i want to insert an option to select the language, i got the following code snippet:

```
<?php

if( isset( $_GET['target'] ) )
    $target = $_GET['target'];
else
    $target = "productie";

if ( isset( $_GET['language']))
    $language = $_GET['language'];
else {
    $language = "ro";
}
?>
```

in the same file (index.php) calling a frame with the menu

```
<FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="files/menu.php?target='<?=$target?>'&language='<?=$language?>'" name=leftFrame marginWidth=0>
```

in the `menu.php` I want to use a dropdown menu with the language options but first i am trying to forward the predefined language option from my `index.php` to any of my webpage in the `index.php` i got this code related to the language variable

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_GET['language']))
    $language = $_GET['language'];
else {
    $language = "ro";
} ?>
```

i tried also from the menu.php to hardcode the language parameter

```
<TD vAlign=top height="2%" valign="top" <?php if( $_GET['target'] == 'productie' ) echo " bgcolor=\"#A0A0A0\" ";?>>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../index.php?target=productie&language=ro" target="_parent">Raport productie</a></TD></TR>
```

but when i go in my productie.php and insert a

```
print_r($_GET);
```

i see only the target variable

```
Array ( [target] => productie )
```

what i am missing?

Comment: When you only show `target` what does the URL display as?

Comment: if i modify the url to `http://webpage/test/index.php?target=productie` i see the same output fro `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: That edit you just made is a huge difference. You close the attribute before giving a value for `language`. Look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: I think it is likely to be: 
<?php echo $target.'&language='.$language ?>
that contains the error.

Comment: sorry i didn't understood what you mean @ivion i am not using the `"` in url or you mean somewhere in the code?

Comment: It is something to do with how you get php variables into this bit of code. It is the way you escape html and go into php, using single quotes or double quotes, I think it's that type of problem, try:

<FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="files/menu.php?target='<?=$target?>'&language='<?=$language?'>" name=leftFrame marginWidth=0>

Comment: @Atrix i received syntax erorr i think it is because of this `<?=$language?'>" name`

Comment: <?=$language?>'"
so, it ends with single quote, then double quote

Comment: @Atrix yes exactly i corrected the syntax but nothing change can i do somewhere a `Print_R()` to find out what is the format? In the browser address bar the GET parameters looks good, but as i said it is handled to the index.php first

Comment: Why don't you set a session variable instead of trying to forward the URL parameter everywhere?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
<FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="files/menu.php?target='<?=$target?>'&language='<?=$language?>'" name=leftFrame marginWidth=0>
```

to

```
<FRAME noResize marginHeight=0 src="files/menu.php?target=<? echo $target?>&language=<? echo $language?>'" name=leftFrame marginWidth=0>
```

You forgot to add echo, instead you used =

Comment: `<?=` is PHP's [short echo tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-echo-tags) and is equivalent to `<?php echo`.

Comment: @kmoser You are 100% right, cant delete it because answer is accepted.