# change css if database gives certain value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm currently trying to write a program that creates an invoice pdf. Now im looking for a way to set a div's style within the pdf to display: none, if the database gives out the country e.g. "germany".
I'm not sure if there is a way to do that within PHP, as I know there is a way using document.getElementById with JS

Tried using document.getElementById, but I am not sure where exactly I have to put that statement.

```
if($data["country"] == "Germany"){
  document.getElementById("vat").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not on the client. JS code needs to be in a JS block `echo '<script...>`... or you need to close the PHP block `?>` then have the code you want in that block. Not sure if that would/wouldn't work though.. I don't think JS could interact with a PDF file. If the PDF is loaded in `vat` it could work.

Comment: Is the PDF being created by javascript or PHP? If it's PHP, I would suggest just not outputting that div at all instead of trying to hide it

Comment: You can use an if-else statement: `if ($data["country"] == "Germany") { echo("<div style=\"color: red;\"></div>"); } else { echo("<div style=\"color: blue;\"></div>"); }` and use any element as a replacement for `<div>` in my example. Make sure to use the \ character to escape double quotes in your echo-statement. This way you create the changable HTML element within PHP instead of within the actual HTML.

Comment: @aynber the PDF is being created by PHP. The div has to be shown for some values and for others it has to be hidden, as the way of working with VAT differs from country to country

Comment: So use `if($data['country'] != 'Germany') { // code for div }` or `if(!in_array($data['country'], ['Germany', 'Country1', 'Country2']) { // code for div }` PDFs are usually static, so there's no need to hide it. Just don't output if you don't need it.

Comment: @aynber some of us remember the dark days when Adobe tried to thrust interactive PDFs on the world. *Shudder*.

Comment: A lot of confusion seems to stem from not being able to differentiate between JS and PHP - they're two completely different languages (for this purpose here) with completely different goals. You _can_ mix PHP with JS, but you're going to end up with JS (on the client) after all. PHP is not a client-side language like JS is.

Answer (score 0):

use shorthand echo tag in an inline style attribute, use php `ternary operator` to check if `$data['country'] == 'Germany'`, if `true` it returns `'display:none;'` if it's `false` it returns `empty string`:

```
    <div id="vat" style="<?= $data['country'] == 'Germany'? 'display:none;':'' ?>" >
    <div/>
```

Comment: @max the `<?=` is still in play and its removal is not on the roadmap of any kind.

Comment: @max That is not a short tag, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386620/php-echo-vs-php-short-echo-tags. From PHP manual from linked thread, `The <?= combined opening and echo tag is not controlled by short_open_tag. It is always available, and will continue to be always available after this RFC.`

Answer (score -1):

```
   <?php if($result == "Germany") { ?> 

    <script>
    document.getElementById("vat").style.display = "none";
   </script>

   <?php } ?>
```

works 100% percent...
when server is sending the page, it checks that if the result matches condition, it adds the script to your html webpage...