# why can't PHP display email verification error?

Tags: php, html, css

I have an input box for email. i wrote code thats supposed verify that there's no error with the email, and if there is, change the input box's border colour to red. it dosent work. heres the code:

```
<?php
$emailError = false;

if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    
    if (empty($email)||!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailError = true;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
            <div class="input-group" id="email-input">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email"
                <?php
                 if ($emailError) {
                    echo "<style> #email {border-color: #ff0000;} </style>";}    
                ?>>
            </div>
            <button id="submit-button" name="submit-button" type="submit">Sign Up!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've seen a very similar question to this before, I think - an hour or two ago. The name of your submit button doesn't match the name you're checking for in your `if()` clause at the start. `-` is not the same as `_`. In any case you should check for form submission using `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")` I think, for various reasons. If that doesn't help, please expand on "it doesn't work" and detail what debugging steps you have taken.

Comment: @droopsnoot yeah, couldnt edit it the last time, so i deleted it and reuploaded it with the correct version. hope its ok.. well first of all, it worked! thank you! and second, when it echo'd the style element, it actually echo'd the code on the screen. how can i make it echo as real code?

Comment: you have used <style> inside body which is wrong, all <style></style> must be between <head></head>

Comment: Adding `<style>` in the HTML is not the cleanest way, you can define a CSS class a use the `if` to add this class to the element that you want.

Comment: so, how can it know im reffering to #email if its not inside of the input itself?

Comment: Adding a `<style>` block _inside_ an element is plain wrong - you'd use a `style` attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style vs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style

Answer (score 1):

Add the style directly on your input:

```
<input style="<?= $emailError ? 'border-color: #ff0000;' : '' ?>" type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email" />
```

Or better yet, just add a `class="someClass"` and define your style in a CSS file.

```
.redBorder {
    border-color: #ff0000
}
```

```
<input class="<?= $emailError ? 'redBorder' : '' ?>" type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email"" />
```

Comment: I would replace `<?=` with `<?php echo` because as the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) says: “*short tags can be disabled it is recommended to only use the normal tags*”.

Comment: @A.L that's not a short opening tag, that's a short echo. Different things, and you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that short opening tag and short echo were different things. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24837835/2257664) for example.

Answer (score 1):

altered method for the above code;  to work as expected: Use inline style attribute for dynamic

```
<?php
$emailError = false;

if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    
    if (empty($email) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailError = true;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="input-group" id="email-input">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email" <?php echo $emailError ? 'style="border-color: #ff0000;"' : ''; ?>>
        </div>
        <button id="submit-button" name="submit_button" type="submit">Sign Up!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```