# PHP echo efficieny comparision

Tags: php

Is PHP `echo $str1, $str2, $str3` faster than `echo $str1 . $str2 . $str3`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are echo and print different in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php) and [a gazillion other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=echo+print+difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but only marginally so, and probably won't impact your web application.  Here's [one of the many articles](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/) that runs through the benchmarks.

Comment: 4 million loops and only a fraction of a second difference = insignificant

Answer (score 1):

The result shows that dot is more preferable if there are no variables or $ symbol involved which is around 200% faster. On the other hand, commas will help to increase around 20%-35% efficiency when dealing with $ symbols.

[source](http://hungred.com/useful-information/php-micro-optimization-tips/)