# PHP: Is there any advantage to using echo instead of print?

Tags: php, printing, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are echo and print different in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php)

As far as I know the difference between `print` and `echo` is that `print` returns a boolean. So whenever I use `echo` I can use `print` instead. Still, in all the code examples I'v seen until now (I'm learning PHP) they used `echo`. Why is that?

EDIT: Maybe the reason is that `echo` is faster than `print` (because `print` returns a value and `echo` doesn't)? Even though, I guess the speed difference is unnoticeable.

Comment: Because `echo` does not return a value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `print` returns a value while `echo` does not making `echo` slightly faster (not a big deal though). You may check out this post for more:

- [echo VS print](http://www.learnphponline.com/php-basics/php-echo-vs-print)

Other than that, you use `echo` to `output` something unlike `print` to get some return value too. Therefore, `echo` gets best in the queue but nothing stops you from using `print`.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how we can give credit to such test. I'm persuaded it can change from versions to versions and depending of the configuration, output buffering or other factors.

Comment: @Savageman: You are right but generally `echo` *is* slightly faster :)

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://terrychay.com/article/the-shuhari-of-quoting.shtml) has explored this question to a greater depth than you may have even known was possible.

From: http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/1/fid/40

1.

```
  Speed. There is a difference between the two, but speed-wise it should be irrelevant which one you use. echo is marginally faster since it doesn't set a return value if you really want to get down to the nitty gritty.
```

2.

```
  Expression. print() behaves like a function in that you can do: $ret = print "Hello World"; And $ret will be 1. That means that print can be used as part of a more complex expression where echo cannot. An example from the PHP Manual:

  $b ? print "true" : print "false";
```

print is also part of the precedence table which it needs to be if it is to be used within a complex expression. It is just about at the bottom of the precedence list though. Only "," AND, OR and XOR are lower.

1. Parameter(s). The grammar is: echo expression [, expression[, expression] ... ] But echo ( expression, expression ) is not valid. This would be valid: echo ("howdy"),("partner"); the same as: echo "howdy","partner"; (Putting the brackets in that simple example serves no purpose since there is no operator precedence issue with a single term like that.)

So, echo without parentheses can take multiple parameters, which get concatenated:

```
   echo  "and a ", 1, 2, 3;   // comma-separated without parentheses
   echo ("and a 123");        // just one parameter with parentheses
```

print() can only take one parameter:

```
   print ("and a 123");
   print  "and a 123";
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `echo` is slightly faster than `print`, though for most purposes it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't change anything. You can use either one or the other. There's no particular use of 1 being returned, everyone use echo by convention, maybe it's historical. It's also faster to write (4 letters instead of 5).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time it just comes down to personal preference.

However `echo` can have have more than one parameter and `print` returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is no, it does not matter which you use. There are minor differences, but it is nothing to worry about. I'll highlight some of them below:

1. `print` can be used in expressions, while `echo` cannot. For example, with `print`, the following is possible: `($foo == true) ? print 'true' : $foo = true`, but replacing with `echo` would cause an error
2. `echo` can take multiple arguments, separated by commas, while `print` cannot. For example, you would do `echo "hello", "world";`
3. `print` always "returns" the value `1`