# Why does print return (int) 1?

Tags: php

I know `echo()` and `print()` do the same thing. but [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) has a return value of  `(int) 1`.

The question is:

1. Why it always returning (int) 1 ?
2. What we can do with returning (int) 1 ?

Comment: that's why echo() better than print()

Comment: From the related links: [How are echo and print different in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are echo and print different in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`print` is a function and can be used in expressions, while `echo` is a language construct that can only be used at the start of the line.

```
 echo print(print(print(print(123)))), print(4);
```

The real use case for having print available as a function is to allow it to be used in expressions. For example as debug feature:

```
 if (($a == $b) and print("It's true") and $c) {
```

Or even

```
 return TRUE and print("right");
```

Comment: "print() is not actually a real function (it is a language construct)" -- [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

Comment: True. It only imitates the behaviour of a function (not e.g. usable as callback). And it's parsed even without parenthesis around the argument.

Comment: hmmm seem like this is the logical reason for (int) 1, thank you very much to give real use case example :)

Answer (score 6):

#### Why it always returning (int) 1 ?

Most likely to signify success, so you could interpret it as the value `TRUE`.

#### What we can do with returning (int) 1 ?

In future code, instead of doing

```
$i++;
```

you can do

```
$i = $i + print("Hello World!\n");
```

(Minor side-effects may apply.)

Comment: I'd go for $i += print('bohaaa!');

Comment: Why in the world would you want to increment a variable with the result of print ?

Answer (score 3):

As others already mentioned, print is pseudo-function (returns a value but not a real function), which makes its use valid in expressions. So you can write quirky code like this to confuse the maintainers :)

```
$success = doSomethingThatCanPossiblyFail();
if ($success || !(print "Failed to do that! Not going to do the follow up")){ 
  //success
  nowDoTheFollowupThing();
}
```

[Just make sure the maintainers don't know where you live](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/coding-for-violent-psychopaths.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a little feature that allows you to use print in conditions, like :

```
if ((print "angry") && (print "mammoth") || (print "will stomp you"))
{
   // always executed
}
```

Now what's the use of this ? No idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can the return value in cases where you actually *have* to count.

Example:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i += print "$i<br>" );
```

You can combine printing and counting here.

Answer (score -1):

print always return 1 if the print work successfully. else it will return 0.
and in echo we can show the successful or unsuccessful of print function.

echo print(1);// 11

if we write print(1) alone it will print to us 1 .

print(1);// 1

one example for better knowing.

---

```
function sum($a,$b)
                    {
        echo $a+$b;
        if($a+$b == true)
                         {
            return 1;

                         }
        else{ return 0;}
                      }
```

// now we call the function

```
sum(3,1);//4
echo "<br>";
echo sum(3,1);// 41
echo "<br>";
sum('abc','xyz');// 0
echo "<br>";
echo sum('abc','xyz');//00
```

---

this code work like print function