# How to print the following line from PHP

Tags: php, escaping, echo

hi friends a simple question.

How to print the following line from PHP echo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

I am confused with escape sequences.

Comment: I think you are looking for that
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486757/how-to-generate-xml-file-dynamically-using-php

Comment: Would you consider selecting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

### Printing the XML

You can either escape the double quotes like so:

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>";
```

or you can use single quotes, and therefore no escaping is needed:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>';
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `print()` method like so:

```
print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>";
```

or

```
print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>';
```

Which one you use, depends on what you would like to achieve. In most cases `echo` is the better option as it is ever so slightly faster.

[**See Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php) for the differences between `echo` and `print`

### Outputting XML to the browser

However, if you are trying to generate XML, then it is also important to output the correct headers for the document, like so:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
```

**This will tell the browser to interpret what you output, as XML**

#### Advanced XML Outputting

To take the XML output a step further, you may want to look into the `simpleXML` extension in PHP.

**[See Here](http://php.net/simplexml)** for more information

Comment: @DevangRathod read the question! He may use the word print, but he asks how to print this using `echo`

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can screen them using "\" (if you have some var in this statement) i.e. echo `"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1"?>\"`;
If no var then just `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>'`
Or you can use $text = `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>'`; echo $text;
Or you can use [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) (use it for big text only)

And read about difference between ' and " in PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
echo <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
XML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put header (to let the browser know how to render the display):

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>";
```