# ECHO does not work in the third exp of FOR LOOP but PRINT does work?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, language-construct

Why is this valid:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; print $i++);
```

and this gives syntax error:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; echo $i++);
```

What's the difference? Both are language constructs.
Is there a rule what is valid and what not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are echo and print different in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, both `echo` and `print` are language constructs, however `print` behaves more like a function than you realize. Internally, `print` is treated like a function by PHP, as it always returns a value (`int 1`).

It is because of this crucial difference, that the PHP interpreter allows for calling **this special** language construct in your `for` loop - because it treats `print` as a function, and as such, it can be used in contexts where normally you would use functions. Consider the following code

```
<?php (1 > 0) ? print 'true' : print 'false'; ?>
```

The code above will work, and it will print 'true'. However, consider the following:

```
<?php (1 > 0) ? echo 'true' : echo 'false'; ?>
<?php (1 > 0) ? return 'true' : yield 'false'; ?>
<?php (1 > 0) ? continue : break; ?>
```

None of these examples are valid, and will throw a fatal parse error warning. It is because language constructs are treated in a somewhat obscure way (especially `print`, which is so special that it works unlike all other constructs), in that they behave like functions in *some* cases, but in others they are very much different.

Consider the following:

```
<?php

    function _echo($a)
    {
        echo $a;
    }

    (1 > 0) ? _echo('true') : _echo('false');

?>
```

This code will work, because we no longer make use of the `echo` language construct directly, but instead we have created a wrapper **function** for it. This function will be executed, and PHP no longer cares what are the contents of that function, or what language constructs we use in there.

Generally, language constructs cannot be used in the context of my second example, or in the context of your `for` loop. This type of syntax is only valid for functions and methods (which is why `print` works and `echo` does not).