# Formatting arrays and nested arrays with the print function in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having problems formatting arrays and nested arrays with print function in PHP.

So far into learning PHP, I have been wrapping print commands with `" "` and putting basic html like `<p>` within the quotes with the single variables, and everything works fine.  Today I have been creating arrays and nested arrays and have been getting some strange behaviour.

For instance:

```
// nested array
$array2 = array(6, "fox", "dog", array("x", "y", "z"));
// display nested array index 1
print "<p> $array2[3][1] </p>";
```

This prints `Array[1]` instead of `y`.

If I do this it prints ok:

```
print "<p>" . $array2[3][1] . "</p>";
```

The last array I am trying to get to print using a print readible with `<pre>` tags.  So far I have tried this, but all I see in the browser is just `array`

```
print_r("<pre>" . $array2 . "</pre>");
```

I must be doing something wrong if the tags will not concat?

Comment: You have to convert an array to string somehow. Check out the PHP's implode function http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: `"<p> {$array2[3][1]} </p>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
print_r("<pre>" . $array2 . "</pre>");
```

You're concatenating the strings `<pre>` and `</pre>` with an array, it automatically converts the array to "Array", and it equal to the following:

```
print_r("<pre>" . (string)$array2 . "</pre>");
```

What you *actually* want to do is use `print_r` on the array itself - not turn it into a string. You can take use of the second parameter in `print_r` to return the value rather than outputting it:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($array2, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks - I noticed your using single quotes, does this matter in this case?  The only time I have used single quotes is in the `$_POST` function so far.  Also, are `echo` and `print` the same?

Comment: [How are echo and print different in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php). Essentially, `echo` is faster, but reacts a little differently (you probably won't notice the difference, so just use `echo`. When using single quotes variables inside do not expand (variable expanding is why `echo "<strong>$test</strong>";` works. Use whichever you prefer as the [speed difference is so minimal that it does not matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

Comment: I see, thanks.  So when you say "expand", what would happen if you wrote `echo '<strong>$test</strong>'` would this still be expanded, but will execute faster?

Comment: @user1574598 No - single quotes don't expand. `$test = 'abc'; echo "<strong>$test</strong>";` would output `<strong>123</strong>`. `$test = 'abc'; echo '<strong>$test</strong>';` would output `<strong>$test</strong>`. Don't bother about which is faster - it's micro optimization and is not needed. Bother about what you find easiest to read.

Answer (score 1):

You should add curly brackets:

```
// nested array
$array2 = array(6, "fox", "dog", array("x", "y", "z"));
// display nested array index 1
print "<p> {$array2[3][1]} </p>";
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> If a dollar sign ($) is encountered, the parser will greedily take as
>   many tokens as possible to form a valid variable name. **Enclose the
>   variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify the end of the
>   name**.