# Whats faster: echo or print? - PHP

Tags: php

Which statement should I be using in PHP? Print or Echo?
In PHP, Echo and Print do the same thing.
Whats the difference? is one of them faster?

Thanks!!

Comment: This question has been deeply answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This is a duplicate. Please refer to:
[How are echo and print different in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php)