# Why echo and print can not be used interchageably in following code snippet?

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error, output, echo

Consider the following simple code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>

            <?php
                $x = 5;
                $y = 4;    

                echo print $x + $y;
            ?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

The output is below :

```
91
```

Now consider the other similar code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>

            <?php
                $x = 5;
                $y = 4;

                print echo $x + $y;
            ?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

The output is below :

```
*a blank white screen*
```

Why so?

If echo and print can be used in a one statement why can't the reverse pattern works?

Please satisfy my query with good explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: @JohnConde:My intention is towards clearing the concept and not giving any importance to the output. The output is just immaterial in this case. I want to clear the concept only.

Comment: Look at the docs for [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) and [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). print returns an _int_ and echo doesn't return anything.

Comment: @watcher: I already knew that. I want to clear my doubt why they can't be used interchangeably?

Comment: `echo` is a language statement, and `print` an unary expression.

Comment: what version of PHP? when I try on PHP 5.5.12 `print echo 12 + 3;` I get `syntax error, unexpected 'echo'`

Comment: @watcher:I'm using PHP 5.5.29(The latest stable version of series 5.5)

Comment: @mario:Could you please explain me what does exactly mean by unary expression? Could you please put more focus on your concepts?

Comment: Pick your duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647322/whats-the-difference-between-echo-print-and-print-r-in-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` is a construct that behaves like a function; it has a return value of `1`. Therefore:

```
echo print 'x';
```

is syntactically valid and produces `x1`, where `x` is printed by `print` and `1` by echo. This is equivalent to:

```
$print_value = print 'x';
echo $print_value;
```

`echo`, on the other hand, has no return value, so `$echo_value = echo 'x';` is a syntax error and so is `print echo 'x';`.